# Difference between scanf() and fgets()

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

I want to know what is the difference between `fgets()` and `scanf()`. I am using C as my platform.

Answer (score 30):

There are multiple differences.  Two crucial ones are:

- `fgets()` can read from any open file, but `scanf()` only reads standard input.
- `fgets()` reads 'a line of text' from a file; `scanf()` can be used for that but also handles conversions from string to built in numeric types.

Many people will use `fgets()` to read a line of data and then use `sscanf()` to dissect it.

Answer (score 8):

Scanf does not perform bounds checking. fgets is likely going to be the better choice. You can then use sscanf() to evaluate it.

Good discussion of the topic here-
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/109243-scanf-vs-fgets.html

[How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf/1247993#1247993) (That was my evil twin getting lectured for forgetting this- not me)

Comment: For numeric types, scanf() does not need to do bounds checking.  For string types, you can tell scanf() to do boundary checking.

Answer (score 8):

```
int scanf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

**scanf(3)** searches for certain *pattern* defined by the *format argument* on the given input known as *stdin*, where the pattern is defined by you. The given input to **scanf(3)**, depending on its variant (scanf, fscanf, sscanf, vscanf, vsscanf, vfscanf), could be a string or a file.

```
char *fgets(char * restrict str, int size, FILE * restrict stream);
```

**fgets(3)** just reads a *line* from the input file *stream* and copy the bytes as null terminating string to the buffer *str* and limit the output to the buffer to given bytes in *size*.

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that `scanf` pattern specs do allow field width limits:

```
scanf( " %80s", mybuffer );
```

But, where `printf()` allows the width to be passed as a variable (with '*'):

```
printf( "My name is %*s.\n", 20, name );
```

`scanf()` does not. (It interprets the '*' as a flag to suppress/ignore the field entirely.) Which means you end up doing things like this:

```
#define NAMEWIDTH 40
char buffer[ NAMEWIDTH + 4 ];
...
scanf( " %40x", buffer );
```

and no way to connect the field width 40 in the `scanf()` with the buffer width 40 in the buffer declaration.

Answer (score 1):

scanf parses a string you read in (or created), and fgets reads a line from an open FILE*. Or do you mean fscanf?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference lies in the fact that *`scanf`* has no limits on the number of characters that can be read (in its default use), while *`fgets`* has a maximum number of char that can be read.

See the prototype of the two functions:

> **char * fgets (char * dest, int size, FILE * stream);**
>
> **int scanf (const char * format, ...);**

You can see that the second parameter of `fgets` imposes to read at most size char.

Another clear difference is the return value: *`fgets`* return a pointer to **`dest`** on success; *`scanf`* return the number of input items successefully matched and assigned.
Then, the *scanf* function scans input according to *format*, and reads input from the standard input stream ***stdin***, while `fgets` reads input from **FILE * stream** as default.

In conclusion, you could use `scanf` to read data from a FILE and insert them into a fixed-size array (for example) does not have much sense.
An advantage of `scanf` is the formatting of output data: if the function reads `12345\n`, the output is `12345`, while the fgets reads and returns till `\n` (included), adding a `\0` in the end as a string terminator.