# What is the simplest way of getting user input in C?

Tags: c, input, io, scanf

There seem to be a LOT of ways you can get user input in C.

What is the easiest way that requires little code?

Basically I need to display this:

```
Enter a file name: apple.text
```

Basically I need to ask the user for a file name. So I need something that just gets that one word that the user will be inputting.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314401/how-to-read-a-line-from-the-console-in-c

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The simplest *"correct"* way is probably this one, taken from Bjarne Stroustrup's paper [Learning Standard C++ As A New Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf).

*(Note: I changed Bjarne's code to check for `isspace()` instead of just end of line.  Also, due to @matejkramny's comment, to use `while(1)` instead of `while(true)`...and so long as we're being heretical enough to edit Stroustrup's code, I've subbed in C89 comments instead of C++ style too.  :-P)*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void quit() /* write error message and quit */
{
    fprintf(stderr, "memory exhausted\n");
    exit(1);
}

int main()
{
    int max = 20;
    char* name = (char*) malloc(max); /* allocate buffer */
    if (name == 0) quit();

    printf("Enter a file name: ");

    while (1) { /* skip leading whitespace */
        int c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) break; /* end of file */
        if (!isspace(c)) {
             ungetc(c, stdin);
             break;
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        int c = getchar();
        if (isspace(c) || c == EOF) { /* at end, add terminating zero */
            name[i] = 0;
            break;
        }
        name[i] = c;
        if (i == max - 1) { /* buffer full */
            max += max;
            name = (char*) realloc(name, max); /* get a new and larger buffer */
            if (name == 0) quit();
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("The filename is %s\n", name);
    free(filename); /* release memory */
    return 0;
}
```

That covers:

- skipping whitespace until you reach character input
- expanding the string buffer dynamically to fit arbitrary size strings
- handling conditions of when memory can't be allocated

Are there simpler but broken solutions, which might even run a bit faster?  Absolutely!!

If you use scanf into a buffer with no limit on the read size, then your input exceeds the size of the buffer, it will create a security hole and/or crash.

Limiting the size of the reading to, say, only 100 unique characters of a filename might seem better than crashing.  But it can be worse; for instance if the user meant `(...)/dir/foo/bar.txt` but you end up misinterpreting their input and overwriting a file called `bar.t` which perhaps they cared about.

It's best to get into good habits early in dealing with these issues.  *My opinion* is that if your requirements justify something close-to-the-metal and "C-like", it's well worth it to consider the jump to C++.  It was designed to manage precisely these concerns--with techniques that are robust and extensible, yet still perform well.

Comment: Even if your class wants you to scanf and move on, I'd suggest putting notes anywhere you knowingly do something broken/expedient.  So next to your read operations just stick in a comment like `/* REVIEW: input correctness, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831755/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-getting-user-input-in-c/ */`  It shows you do your research, keeps the link for later reading. Plus anyone debugging a codebase who is getting a mystery crash can have their attention drawn--seeing not only the warning but a pointer to a discussion of the correct solution.

Comment: Btw the question asks for C not C++

Comment: @matejkramny In the paper I cite and quote, Bjarne Stroustrup contrasts the "C way" to the "C++ way". This is his "C way" code that I am presenting.  It is not C++ code. Point of the paper is that this "correct" C code can be expressed in C++ more saliently and with no loss of efficiency; which may surprise die-hard C programmers.  I assure you I can read the question; I just thought one of the best answers I'd read to how to write the "correct" C version of what C++ does for you by default came from a paper written that was a work of C++ evangelism. You should read the paper, though it's old.

Comment: C++ has boolean defined, which don't exist (by default) in C. Thats why I thought this is C++ code, for a C question

Comment: I'd also like to know why there are two while loops, it seems you only need one? (pardon my ignorance)

Comment: @matejkramny I could mention that C99 has stdbool.h...except for the fact that I don't know what you are talking about as there is no `bool` in this answer.  The first loop skips leading whitespace.  Please read [Learning Standard C++ as a New Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/new_learning.pdf) if you'd like this code explained, as it covers this example in C and C++ and others.

Comment: There is `while(true)` which my compiler whined about. I understand the stuff now though, thanks :)

Comment: @matejkramny Ah, missed that--thanks for pointing it out! I guess Bjarne's compiler didn't complain. Modified to use `while(1)` instead.

Comment: Also, i feel that `malloc` and `realloc` are not allocating enough memory. It should be `malloc(max * sizeof(char))` no? Additionally, C doesn't care that `malloc` returns `void*` so the implicit conversion is not required.

Comment: @matejkramny [sizeof(char) is always 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2215454/211160).  As for the `(char*)` cast not being necessary, it doesn't *hurt* to have it...and if someone is in the habit of writing both C and C++ code then putting in such casts makes it easier if one often switches between languages, or is writing code in the (extremely large) subset of C that can also be compiled correctly with C++.

Comment: There needs to be a curly brace on this line.  I can't edit it in since it's just one character:  if (isspace(c) || c == EOF) /* at end, add terminating zero */

Comment: `EOF` can be caused by error. POSIX specifies following errors: `EAGAIN`, `EBADF`, `EINTR`, `EIO`, `EOVERFLOW`, `ENOMEM` and `ENXIO`. The `ferror()` or `feof()` functions must be used to distinguish between an error condition and an end-of-file condition.

Answer (score 7):

`scanf` seems to work in a non-hostile environment.  In other words, you're making a simple utility program for yourself.

BUFSIZ usually far exceeds the size limits of UNIX pathnames.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char str[BUFSIZ];                                                                                                                                                                             

  printf("Enter a file name: ");                                                                                                                                                                
  scanf("%s", str);                                                                                                                                                                             

  printf("You entered: %s\n", str);                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

If you need to accumulate data in a program that could be the target of buffer overrun, you might need a bit more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * prompt_and_read(const char * prompt) {
  char * response;
  char * bufsize;

  printf("%s", prompt);
  asprintf(&bufsize, "%%%us", BUFSIZ);

  if((response = malloc(BUFSIZ + 1)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"out of memory\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  scanf(bufsize, response);
  free(bufsize);
  return response;
}

int main ( void ) {
  char * pathname;

  pathname = prompt_and_read("Enter a file name: ");
  printf("You entered: [%s]\n", pathname);
  free(pathname);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what happens if the string exceeds BUFSIZ...?

Comment: That is truly possible, but I was under the impression he wanted to input filenames in a non-hostile environment.  ;-)  If it was hostile, he'd have to do something a bit more involved.  And he did ask for a solution that involved only a little code.

Comment: Hostile version just posted.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char file[100];
    printf("File Name?: \n");
    fgets(file, 100, stdin);
    printf("Your input: %s", file);
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252132/difference-between-scanf-and-fgets

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a file name:";

    string filepath;
    cin >> filepath;
}
```

Comment: Well that's in C++, which you originally had your question tagged as.

Comment: Don't tag your question as `C++` then ಠ_ಠ. Use `scanf` in C

Answer (score 1):

you should write your own fgets() wrapper function that reads a line of input into a buffer of a specified size and that removes the newline char that fgets() also reads. you could also return a status of whether or not the whole line was able to fit into the buffer (ie. is the newline at the end of the buffer). you shouldn't ever really use scanf or gets unless you want overflows.

EDIT: thought i might provide some basic code:

```
typedef unsigned char BOOL;
#define TRUE   1
#define FALSE  0

/* wraps fgets, returns FALSE if the whole line couldn't fit into the buffer */
BOOL read_input(char *dest, size_t len)
{
   /* our temp buffer needs to hold the extra new line char (len + 1)
        * should also add error checking to malloc */
   BOOL bSuccess = TRUE;
   size_t total_len = len + 1;
   char *temp = (char*) malloc( total_len * sizeof(char) );

   fgets(temp, total_len, stdin);

   /* if the whole line wasn't read, we'll return FALSE but still copy temp into dest */
   if (temp[strlen(temp) - 1] != '\n')
      bSuccess = FALSE;
   else
      temp[strlen(temp) - 1] = '\0'; /* overwrite the '\n' if it does infact exist */

   strcpy(dest, temp);

   free(temp);
   return bSuccess;
}
```

Comment: Well this is for a simple (well ok, not so simple) programming assignment. Just want to pass the class at this point. Not going to over complicate. Thanks though!

Comment: The above can easily be done in under 10 lines, it really depends on how many times you'd need to repeat the functionality. Depending on the use of your input, that newline char can also sometimes cause problems. And it's also worth noting that if fgets is unable to fit the whole line into your buffer you might want to remove the extra input up until you encounter a newline (fgetc in a loop).

Comment: `scanf` has character limits, such as `scanf("%99s", mySize100Buffer);`.  But unlike `fgets` the bound is specified by a digit string, so capturing the BUFSIZE-1 relationship involves generating a custom format string.  Somewhat impractical...

Comment: EDIT: here's some code to show how simple you could have it (don't copy it so you don't get busted for plagiarism).

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
main()
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    char c,buf[100];

start:
    printf("Enter the name:");
    while ( (c=getchar()) != '\n' )
    {
            buf[i++]=c;
            buf[i]='\0';
    }
    if ( buf[0] == '\0')
    {
    printf("invalid name\n");
    goto start;
    }
    else
    printf("Your name is valid\nName = %s\n",buf);
      }
```