# When reading a C-style string in c++ an error appears

Tags: c++

Firstly, look at the following simple code.

```
int main(){
    char *name;
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Your name is: " << name;

    return 0;
}
```

The previous code gives me the following error `warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'`.
but I have been solved the problem by:

```
const char *name;
```

After compile the code, I have another error `no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'const char*')`.

**What the reason of the previous error, and how to solve it ?**

Comment: `char *` does not allocate any storage for the string to go in. You should use `std::string name;` instead.

Comment: Both versions (with and without `const`) have partly the same, partly different problems. But since you tagged the question 'c++': Why not use a std::string to avoid memory/pointer issues altogether?

Comment: You won't get that warning from that code. I guess it's actually something like `char * name = "something";`. In any case, you can't write to a string constant or an uninitialised pointer, so use `std::string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't initialized any memory into which the string can be read. `char *` is a pointer to a location in memory where a string *can* be read, but the memory first has to be allocated using `new` or `malloc`.

However, in C++ there is another, better option: use `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Your name is: " << name;

    return 0;
}
```

If you are set on using a c-string, you could do allocate memory and do something like the following:

```
int main()
{
    char name[MAX_SIZE];
    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin.get(name, MAX_SIZE);
    cout << "Your name is: " << name;

    return 0;
}
```

(Thanks to Neil Kirk for the improvements)

Comment: I don't care about use `c` or `c++`, is there is no way to use c-string ?

Comment: @Sunrise Yes but why do you want to?

Comment: @Sunrise: Yes, but it's more complicated and error-prone. Why would you want to?

Comment: It is just for practice, but please give me any way to use c-string works with my code.

Comment: What if the input is more than 1024 characters?

Comment: @Sunrise If you tag a question [tag:c++], people will advise you based on the nature of C++ programming.  If you insist on C, please see ["What is the simplest way of getting user input in C"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831755/what-is-the-simplest-way-of-getting-user-input-in-c)...and you might realize that all the low-level concerns in managing that is what makes C++ advocates favor C++.  Because there's a lot of room for error in C. You could of course use an entirely different language, but C++ has some interesting traits and advantages...including high C compatibility when needed.

Comment: @Neil - Good catch. All the more reason to leave C behind!

Comment: @Sunrise `char buffer[MAX_SIZE]; cin.get(buffer, MAX_SIZE);`