# Segmentation Fault when trying to use scanf on a struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc, scanf

I'm pretty new to c and I'm pretty frustrated at the moment as well. Here's the code I have:

```
typedef struct {

char* fName;
char* lName;
char* pNum;
char* address;
char* email;
} contactInfo;

void addContact(){
contactInfo *contact;
contact = (contactInfo *) malloc (sizeof(contactInfo));

printf("\n[Add a contact]\nFirst Name: ");
scanf("%s", contact->fName);
printf("%s", contact->fName);
}
```

For some reason when I enter a value for the scanf it gives me a segmentation fault. If I try to add a & in front of the contact->fName I get an error as well.

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: You should allocate memory for all the `char *` in your struct.

Comment: Never typecast the result of malloc in C. Read [this](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, don't worry - frustration is normal with beginning C :)

Since you say you're a beginner, I've written a pretty long answer that explains some other improvements you might want to make. Sorry if I cover some things you already know. Here's a summary:

1. You'll need to allocate some space for the `char*`s to point to **(this is what's causing the crash)**
2. Make sure you check the return value from malloc
3. Make sure ask `scanf()` to only read as many characters as you can hold in your string.
4. No need to cast the return value from malloc.
5. Remember to `free()` anything you've malloc-ed.

---

#### You'll need to allocate some space for the `char*`s to point to

In C, a `char*` means "a pointer to a char". `char*` is commonly used for strings, since you can index pointers like they were arrays - for example, assuming:

```
 char *a = "Hello";
```

Then,  `a[1]` means "the first `char` after the char pointed to by `a`, in this case `'e'`;

You have this code:

```
contactInfo *contact;
contact = (contactInfo *) malloc (sizeof(contactInfo));
```

At this point, you've declared a pointer to a contactInfo struct, and allocated memory of the right size to it. However, the pointers inside the structure currently don't point to anything - so your program is crashing when it calls `scanf()`. You need to also allocate space for the  characters you're about to read, for example:

```
contact->fName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
```

Will allocate space for 10 chars. You'll need to do this for every `char*` in the struct.

A couple of asides that I don't want you to worry about too much:

- In C, `sizeof(char)` is always 1, so you could have written `malloc(10)`, but in my opinion that's less readable.
- You can also do something like:

  ```
  contact->fName = malloc(sizeof(*(contact->fName)) * 10);
  ```

  This is robust to changes in the type of `fName` - you'll always allocate enough space for 10 of whatever `fName` points to.

#### Make sure you check the return value from malloc

Back on track now - you should also check the return value from `malloc()`:

```
contact->fName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
if(contact->fName == NULL) {
   // Allocation failed 
}
```

In some cases, you might be able to recover from a failed allocation (say, trying to 
allocate again, but asking for less space), but to start with:

```
contact->fName = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
if(contact->fName == NULL) {
   printf(stderr,"Allocation of contact->fName failed");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Is probably fine. Many programmers will write a wrapper for `malloc()` that does this error checking for them, so that they no longer have to worry about it.

#### Make sure you only ask `scanf()` to  read as many characters as you can hold in your string.

Note that once you've allocated say 10 char in `fName`, `scanf()` might read too many characters. You can explictly tell scanf the limit by writing `"%Ns"` where N is the maximum number of characters in your string (minus 1 for the null terminator at the end). So, if you've allocated 10 characters, then you should write:

```
scanf("%9s", contact->fName);
```

#### No need to cast the return value from malloc.

One final point - [you don't need to cast the return value of malloc in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565552/790070), so I'd probably write:

```
 contact =  malloc (sizeof(contactInfo));
```

#### Remember to `free()` anything you've malloced

You might be doing this already, but every time you `malloc()` anything, make sure you have a corresponding `free()` in your code once you're done with it. This tells the operating system it can have the memory back. So, if you've got somewhere

```
 contact =  malloc (sizeof(contactInfo));
```

Later on, when you're done with that contact, you'll need to have something like:

```
 free(contact);
```

to avoid memory leaks.

As soon as you've freed something, you aren't allowed to access it any more. So, if you've malloced strings inside the contact, you'll have to first free them:

```
 free(contact->fName);  // doing this in the other order might crash
 free(contact);
```

A few things to remember about free:

1. You can't free anything twice. To avoid this, a good practice is to write:

   ```
    if(contact != NULL) free(contact); 
    contact = NULL;
   ```

   If you write this way, then you'll need to also initialise all pointers to NULL when you create them. When you create structs that have pointers in them, an easy way to do this is to use [`calloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) instead of `malloc()` to create the struct, since `calloc()` returns memory which is always zeroed.
2. When your program exits, all memory is released back to the operating system. This means you don't *technically* need to `free()` things that are around for the lifetime of the program. However, I'd recommend getting into the habit of freeing everything you've malloced, because otherwise you'll forget one day when it's important.

---

#### Further improvements

As a commenter points out on another answer, using magic numbers (numbers hard coded in your code) is generally bad practice. In the examples I've given you above, I've hard coded "10" into the program as the size of the string. However, it's better to do something like:

```
#define FNAME_MAX_LENGTH 10
```

and then later go:

```
malloc(sizeof(char) * FNAME_MAX_LENGTH);
```

This has the advantage that if you need to change the size of the string anywhere, you can change it in just one place. It also prevents you accidentally typing 100 or 1 in one place, causing a potentially serious, hard-to-find bug.

Of course, now that you've got a `#define` for the length, you'll need to update the `scanf()` call where we specify the length. However, since `scanf()` needs the length - 1, you won't be able to use the `#define` to specify the length (at least, not in any nice readable way).

Consequently, you might be interested in [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html), which reads up to a specified length -1 (or until the end of the line - whichever is first). You could then do:

```
fgets(contact->fName,FNAME_MAX_LENGTH,stdin);
```

instead of the `scanf()` call. Another good reason to make this change is that `scanf()` can be [kind of a pain](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html).

So, in addition to the summary above:

1. Using a #define for the length of the string can avoid problems and make it easier to change your code later.
2. `fgets()` is easier to use than `scanf()`, and is more compatible with using a `#define` for the string length.

Comment: ...and do not forget the free()'s.

Comment: @PeterMiehle Oh, alright ;) I've added a section about freeing to my million word answer :)

Comment: Wow this is more than I could have asked for, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestion from @AdamMihalcin, I have give a almost complete code which I hope will serve you as a reference.

Few points to NOTE:

1. The return value of `malloc()` should be checked. Because `malloc()` gets memory from heap and if there is not enough memory, then `malloc()` may return `NULL`. To know more about `malloc` you can read its man page - `man malloc`
2. All the `malloc`'ed memory must be `free`'ed.
3. [Difference between scanf() and fgets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252132/difference-between-scanf-and-fgets) and [C - scanf() vs gets() vs fgets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302255/c-scanf-vs-gets-vs-fgets) explains why `fgets()` is preferred over `scanf()`

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* 
define the length of each filed 
in the contactInfo struct 
*/
#define L_fName     10
#define L_lName     10
#define L_pNum      10
#define L_address   25  
#define L_email     15

typedef struct {
    char* fName;
    char* lName;
    char* pNum;
    char* address;
    char* email;
} contactInfo;

contactInfo * release_ci(contactInfo * contact) 
{
    if (contact == NULL) return NULL;
    free(contact->fName);
    free(contact->lName);
    free(contact->pNum);
    free(contact->address);
    free(contact->email);
    free(contact);
    return NULL;
}

contactInfo * alloc_ci()
{
    contactInfo *contact;
    if ((contact = malloc(sizeof(contactInfo))) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory for contactInfo \n");
        goto free_and_fail;
    }

    if ((contact->fName = malloc(sizeof(char) * L_fName)) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory for fName\n");
        goto free_and_fail;
    }

    if ((contact->lName = malloc(sizeof(char) * L_lName)) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory for lName\n");
        goto free_and_fail;
    }

    if ((contact->pNum = malloc(sizeof(char) * L_pNum)) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory for pNum\n");
        goto free_and_fail;
    }

    if ((contact->address = malloc(sizeof(char) * L_address)) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory for address\n");
        goto free_and_fail;
    }

    if ((contact->email = malloc(sizeof(char) * L_email)) == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR: unable to allocate memory for email\n");
        goto free_and_fail;
    }

    return contact;

free_and_fail:
    release_ci(contact);
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    contactInfo *ci = alloc_ci();

    if (!ci) return -1;

    printf("Enter fName     : ");
    fgets (ci->fName,   L_fName,    stdin);    
    printf("Enter lName     : ");
    fgets (ci->lName,   L_lName,    stdin);    
    printf("Enter pNum      : ");
    fgets (ci->pNum,    L_pNum,     stdin);    
    printf("Enter address   : ");
    fgets (ci->address, L_address,  stdin);    
    printf("Enter email     : ");
    fgets (ci->email,   L_email,    stdin);    

    /* TODO: validation for all the input fields */

    release_ci(ci);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Close (and still work +1).  However, to be bulletproof while using `free_and_fail` as you do, you need to `calloc` contact, not `malloc`.  Whenever you `malloc`, contact gets filled with garbage, so you might fail on the allocation of `contact->pNum`, find that `contact->email` is non-null, and then try to free whatever those garbage bytes point to.  If you `calloc`, then contact gets filled with zeros, so `calloc->email` will actually be null if and when the `contact->pNum` allocation fails.

Comment: Did you mean to make a new post instead of editing your old answer?  Your cleanup code could be a lot nicer (`free(NULL)` is a no-op, so there's no need to check its argument first; `alloc_ci` could have leveraged `release_ci` instead of duplicating code).

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: Strictly speaking, `calloc` isn't any better since the null pointer is not guaranteed to be all-bits-zero.

Comment: @jamesdlin w.r.t clean up, we should not call `free(contact->fName);` if `contact` is `NULL`, so I've put a check `if (contact == NULL) return NULL;` at the beginning. Yes, `alloc_ci()` can use `release_ci()` and I have modified it now.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate memory for all the `char *` in your struct.

For example:

```
contact->fName =  malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
```

Also, you should check the return value of `malloc()`

Comment: I'm close to upvoting this one.  But the OP is obviously a novice, so I'll upvote if you show an example of how to check the return value of `malloc`, and talk about not putting magic numbers like 10 directly in your code (and using a `#define` instead).  Bonus points for pointing the OP to [fgets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html), which protects you from the buffer overflow vulnerabilities that `scanf` does nothing about.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin Good. Thanks for reminding that `help` should be complete!

Comment: No need to cast the return value of `malloc`, and the `(int)` cast is also unnecessary.

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj The typecast of the result of malloc is not only useless, it is also dangerous. Read [this](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc). You should remove the typecast.