# Input validation using a function in C

Tags: c, validation

I'm validating user input through functions.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_income(double *pschool, double *pincome);
double get_double(void);

main()
{
    get_income(&pschool, pincome);
}

void get_income(double *pschool, double *pincome) {
    int tuition, supplies;

    printf("Enter tuition:");
    scanf("%d", &tuition);
    printf("Enter supplies:")
    scanf("%d", &supplies);

    *pSchool = tuition + supplies;
    return;
}

double get_double(void) {
    // validation code should go in here 
}
```

I need to validate the user supplied values for `tuition` and `supplies` to ensure they're both 0 or greater and not empty. Negative values or anything other than numeric digits should not be accepted.

The validation code should be in the `get_double` function and I can't seem to figure out how I can validate something that resides in a separate function. Looking for guidance please.

Comment: why does the validation code need to be in get_double() instead of get_income()? right now its impossible to do what you want because get_double() has no way of knowing what the values of pschool and pincome are, they would either need to be passed to the function (preferable) or made global variables.

Comment: That how i have been asked to do... maybe I have done something wrong... instruction only said that validation code should be in get_double however, i think it may could be done If i dont put scanf code in get_expenses function.. do you propose a better and close solution to me ?

Comment: At the very least, use `int main()` because C99 (C11) requires the `int` and only C99 (C11) allows you to miss the return off the end of `main()`.  If your compiler is not complaining, you have not got enough warnings enabled.

Answer (score 0):

to me, it sounds like the purpose of get_double() is to handle the user input. So this is what i'd do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_double(double *in)
{
    scanf("%d", in);
    if (*in < 0) {
        printf("error message");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void get_income(double ptuition, double psupplies, double *pschool)
{
    *pschool = ptuition + psupplies;
}

int main(void)
{
    double ptuition, psupplies, pschool;

    printf("Enter tuition: ");
    if (get_double(&ptuition)) {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nEnter supplies: ");
    if (get_double(&psupplies)) {
        return 1;
    }

    get_income(ptuition, psupplies, &pschool);
    printf("Total school cost: %f", pschool);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: okay and how do I validate that user did not input anything but numbers ? @chris-dueck

Answer (score 0):

For me, I don't really like to use `scanf` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252132/difference-between-scanf-and-fgets). Here is what will I do to address your problem:

1. Allocate array of chars. to act as the buffer to which input will be written. The size in general needs to reflect the use. That is, if I am only receiving a number no larger than `1000` (integral type), then I would only allocate 6 chars. The last two is for the `'\n'` and `'\0'`.
2. Initialize the one before the last element in the array to `'\n'`to detect overflows.
3. Use `fegts()` function to receive the input.
4. Check for overflow by checking if the one before the last element that I initialized to `'\n'` was changes. If so, I report overflow error, otherwise continue execution.
5. Use `atof()` or `atoi()` functions to convert to double or integer value respectively.

I would like to know if my approach contains any kind of bugs, but as far I know, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with the code, including:

- not checking the `scanf()` function finds data
- incorrect declaration of `main()`
- passing unused pointers to `get_income()`
- not returning statuses from checking functions
- not reporting on entered data
- not declaring variables in `main()`
- function names not matching purpose
- reading integers for storage in floating point numbers
- etc.

You'd probably do better with "read a line and parse it with `sscanf()`" than "let `scanf()` read data"; it is easier to handle the error reporting.

These observations lead to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_tuition_and_supplies(double *ptuition, double *psupplies);
int get_double(double *pvalue);

int main(void)
{
    double tuition, supplies;
    if (get_tuition_and_supplies(&tuition, &supplies) == 0)
        printf("Tuition: %.2f; supplies %.2f\n", tuition, supplies);
    return(0);
}

int get_tuition_and_supplies(double *ptuition, double *psupplies)
{
    int rc = -1;    // Failure
    printf("Enter tuition: ");
    if (get_double(ptuition) == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter supplies: ");
        if (get_double(psupplies) == 0)
            rc = 0;
    }
    return rc;
}

int get_double(double *pvalue)
{
    char buffer[4096];
    int rc = -1;
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "EOF (or error) reading data\n");
    else if (sscanf(buffer, "%lf", pvalue) != 1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Did not find a number in input (%.32s)\n", buffer);
    /* Could check for no extracharacters (blanks allowed) up to newline */
    else if (*pvalue < 0.0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Value (%g) may not be negative\n", *pvalue);
    else
        rc = 0;
    return rc;
}
```

The idiom of 'set return code (`rc`) to failure until proven successful' is one effective technique for handling validation.  It might be better to include the prompting in the `get_double()` function, so that its signature becomes:

```
int get_double(const char *prompt, double *pvalue);
```

This allows you to simplify the code in `get_tuition_and_supplies()` to:

```
int rc = -1;    // Failure
if (get_double("Enter tuition: ", ptuition) == 0 &&
    get_double("Enter supplies: ", psupplies) == 0)
    rc = 0;
return rc;
```

This extends neatly to handling multiple values instead of just two.