# Printing and scanning in C

Tags: c, loops, printf, scanf

I need to ask the user how high and wide a comment box to draw and then when I run the compiler it will draw such a box of the appropriate size. Here is my code that I am using:

```
int main() {
    int i;

    writePattern('/', '*', '/', ' ', ' ',1, LENGTH-2,1,0,0, LENGTH); //top of box being created

    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
        writePattern('/', '*', ' ', '*', '/', 1,1, LENGTH-4, 1,1, LENGTH); //sides of box

    writePattern('/', '*', '/', ' ', ' ', 1 , LENGTH-2,1,0,0,LENGTH); //bottom of box

    return 0;
}
```

So how would I do this? I am new to C so I need some help. I know I will have to use the printf and scanf functions do read in user input but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: The `writePattern(...)` function is not implemented yet? Do you want it to be implemented?

Comment: I didn't show all of the code...but it is implemented. This is just the part of the code that I need to use to ask the user how high and wide they want the comment box to be and then when I run the compiler it will draw the box of the specified size.

Comment: Don't edit the title and question to complete nothingness, either accept an answer or leave it open so other people can search and find help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want help on the printing and scanning?

```
int x, y;
printf("How wide do you want your box?");
if (!scanf("%d", &x))
    //printf that they did it incorrectly and try again, probably in a while loop
printf("how wide?");
if (!scanf("%d", &y))
    //printf that they did it incorrectly and try again, probably in a while loop
```

where `%d` would take or print a number, `%s` a string, `%f` a fraction, etc you can look any others up.

EDIT: woops i forgot the & to reference the addresses of the variables

EDIT2: added suggested error handling

Comment: What about checking the return value for `scanf()` call? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
printf("Enter the width: ");
int width;
if (scanf("%d", &width) != 1) {
    printf("Invalid number!");
    return 1; // Just return nothing or some error code?
}

printf("Enter the height: ");
int height;
if (scanf("%d", &height) != 1) {
    printf("Invalid number!");
    return 1; // Just return nothing or some error code?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before going any further ... It is a very wise thought to learn such a beautiful language ! But when you get started, make sure you do the right thing right from the beginning.

I would advise you not to use the `scanf()` function. It will lead to your program failure if the user does not type in the requested thing. You would rather call general stream functions such as `fgets()` and then parse the string you get. Take a look at this other so question : [Difference between scanf() and fgets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252132/difference-between-scanf-and-fgets)
You might get useful tips over there.