# using scanf function with pointers to character

Tags: c, scanf

I have written the following piece of code:

```
int main() {
  char arrays[12];
  char *pointers;
  scanf("%s", arrays);
  scanf("%s", pointers);
  printf("%s", arrays);
  printf("%s", pointers);
  return 0;
}
```

Why does it give an error when I write `scanf("%s", pointers)`?

Answer (score 16):

```
char *pointers;
```

must be initialized. You can not scan string into `pointers` until you point it to some address. The computer needs to know where to store the value it reads from the keyboard.

```
int main() {
  char arrays[12];
  char *pointers = arrays;
  scanf("%s", pointers);
  printf("%s", pointers);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I like how you gave the alternative to `malloc`.

Answer (score 10):

Because you're writing to an address in memory that has not been initialized. Writing to memory pointer by an uninitialized pointer invokes undefined behaviour. Either allocate enough memory:

```
pointers = malloc(256);
if(!pointers)
  perror("malloc");
else
  scanf("%255s", pointers);
```

Or declare it as a static array:

```
char pointers[256];
```

You should also consider using [fgets()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fgets.html) instead of scanf().

You may want to read i you are interested in fgets():

[Difference between scanf() and fgets()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252132/difference-between-scanf-and-fgets)

Comment: "*pointers by default points to NULL" This is such a fallacy.

Comment: sure? pointer is not guaranted to be NULL, it is not a static variable

Comment: @KingsIndian, the code in that edit is severely broken. In addition, scanf will behave differently to fgets when you give it the %s format specifier.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Fixed the typos. I only suggested fgets(). I didn't say they are equivalent and alternative for each other. I expect anyone to read manual before using if the person is unaware of how a standard function works.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue hehe, anyway I added link to manual and another question describing differences :)

Answer (score 5):

- `char *pointers;` creates a pointer variable.
- `pointers` is the `address` pointed to by `pointers`, which is indeterminate by
  default.
- `*pointers` is the data in the address pointed to by `pointers`, which you cannot do until address is assigned.

Just do this.

```
char arrays[12];
char *pointers;
pointers = arrays;
scanf("%s",pointers);
```

Comment: s/which is NULL by default/which is indeterminate by default/

Answer (score 3):

`pointers` is being used without initialisation, like `int x; printf("%d\n", x);`. You need to make your pointer point to something before using it. Which book are you reading?

Answer (score 1):

`pointers` is an unitialized pointer. You are not able to write into it. You shall allocate enough memory to store a string, as you did with `arrays`.  With a pointer, it is possible to use dynamic allocation (cf. `malloc`).

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on the error, i'm not around a compiler right now.

But for scanf and printf to work you must have this at the top of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Both are standard libraries for C. IO contains scanf, I'm fairly sure printf is in the same. But until you know which libraries you need for which functions it doesn't hurt to include both standard libraries for every program. Try to use custom header files as well so you don't need mass #includes for every file.

Don't forget `malloc` statements for memory allocation.

But I'm unsure what you're attempting to do with your code, please elaborate?

Comment: This is not an answer at all. Not having the headers is not even a cuase for the crash