# Why is getchar() reading '\n' after a printf statement?

Tags: c, newline, printf, getchar

I'm prompting the user to enter the length of an array, initializing a char[] array with this input, and then prompting the user to type a message to enter into the char[] array.

I'm reading the first character of the user's message with `getchar()`.

However, `getchar()` is reading the new-line escape `'\n'` before it is reading any user input. It seems to be getting `'\n'` from the previous `printf` statement that prompts the user...

Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int len = 0,
        originalLen = 0;

    printf("\n\nWhat is the length of the array? ");
    scanf("%d", &originalLen);
    char str[originalLen]; // intitializing the array

    printf("Enter a message to enter into the array: ");
    char target = getchar();
    str[len] = target;

    // why is getchar() reading '\n'?
    if (target == '\n') {
        printf("\n...what happened?\n");
    }
    return 0;
} // end of main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter the number and hit the ENTER key, a number and a character are placed in the input buffer, they are namely:

- The entered number and
- The newline character(`\n`).

The number gets consumed by the `scanf` but the newline remains in the input buffer, which is read by `getchar()`.

You need to consume the `\n` before calling `getchar()` by using:

```
scanf("%d ", &originalLen);
         ^^^
```

This tells `scanf` to read the number and an additional character, which is `\n`.

Comment: Ah thanks @Alok, that makes sense -- it's hitting the ENTER key that adds the `'\n'` character. Is `scanf` frowned upon for this reason?

Comment: @IanCampbell: Yes, for this and many more. such as: *type safety, input validation and so on* . It should be avoided while reading characters and strings but it is okay to use it for simple numeric inputs.

Comment: Thanks @Alok, interesting... so what's a better alternative to `scanf` for characters and Strings?

Comment: @IanCampbell: [`fgets` always!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252132/difference-between-scanf-and-fgets)

Answer (score 4):

It's because the previous `scanf` does *not* read the newline after the number.

This can be solved two ways:

1. Use e.g. `getchar` to read it
2. Add a space after the `scanf` format (e.g. `scanf("%d ", ...)`)

Comment: Thanks @Joachim, so it seems that you have to use the extra space hack for `scanf`... is there a better alternative, or is this professionally accepted?

Comment: @IanCampbell I wouldn't call it a "hack", it simply tells `scanf` to read (and discard) whitespace. As for "professionally accepted", I've used it myself a lot and seen it in a lot of other code as well, so it's not uncommon.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getchar` in a loop to flush out stdin before reading the next character.

```
while((target = getchar()) != '\n' && target != EOF)
```