# Why does moving printf() in a while loop that uses getchar() produce different results?

Tags: c

I'm new to C, sorry if this question is basic. I'm trying to understand the behaviour of the `getchar()` function.

Here I have two versions of my code:

The first one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
        printf(" hello\n");
    }
}
```

when I enter 12 and hit the return key this one produces:

```
12
1 hello
2 hello
```

and then there's the other one where I move printf() up, enter the same input

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        printf(" hello\n");
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

and it produces:

```
12
1 hello
2 hello

 hello
```

Why won't these two work the same way and why does that extra hello appear at the end of the second code.

Comment: try changing it to `printf("hello %d\n", c);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is getchar() reading '\n' after a printf statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765226/why-is-getchar-reading-n-after-a-printf-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that you have provided an input of 3 characters - `'1', '2'` and a newline (`\n`).
Given that let's trace what your programs are doing:

First snippet:

```
Read '1' -> 
Print '1' -> 
Read '2' -> 
Print "hello\n" -> 
Print '2' -> 
Read '\n' -> 
Print "hello\n" -> 
Print '\n' -> 
wait for more input
```

So the last thing printed is newline.

Second snippet:

```
Read '1' -> 
Print '1' ->  
Print "hello\n" -> 
Read '2' -> 
Print '2' -> 
Print "hello\n" -> 
Read '\n' -> 
Print '\n' -> 
Print "hello\n" -> 
wait for more input.
```

So it is first printing the newline and then `"hello"`.

In short, both snippets perform an equal number of iterations, but in the first one the last `printf(" hello\n")` is blocked by the `getchar` when there is no more input. Which is not the case in the second snippet.