# how to loop user input and copy it to file until "exit" string in entered using C?

Tags: c, string, console, user-input

I want to write some small program that is getting strings from the user(using console) when max input is 100 characters , and when user pressed enter - it will copy the input to some file.
I want to exit the loop when user enters the string "exit"

for example : 
"hi how are you?"
" bla bla"
"exit"
 I just don't get how to make it work - should I use scanf? getchar? fgets?

```
char* buf ;
int i;


 buf = (char*)calloc(100, sizeof(char));
 while(1) 
  {
     fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
     if (strcmp(s , "exit") == 0)
       break;
     else
   ...write to file...
   }
```

do I need manually put "\0" ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgets()` is fine, but in some implementations, it puts the trailing newline (`\n`) to the end of the line. You have to remove it in order the comparison to work, or prepare your comparison to accept both `"exit"` and `"exit\n"`:

```
if (strcmp(s , "exit") == 0 || strcmp(s , "exit\n") == 0)
   break;
```

or

```
fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
char *p = strchr(s, '\n');
if (p) *p = 0;

if (strcmp(s , "exit") == 0)
    break;
```

Sidenote: unless you intend to return the string to a caller function, there's no need for using `calloc()` at all. Use an automatic array instead:

```
char s[0x100]; // or whatever
```

Comment: thank you! another thing that I'm not quite sure- if I have an array and i want to place this string there- should I now go threw every letter and copy it : arr[i] = s[i] ? till I get to '\0' ?

Comment: @user1386966 Yes, but don't do that manually. `strncpy(dest, buf, destsize);`, but read the man page for `strncpy()` because it's not safe if you don't check its return value.

Comment: "Some implementations" being a superset of the conforming implementations, "No additional characters are read after a new-line character (**which is retained**)". If there is space (according to the size argument), `fgets` must store the newline in the buffer.

Comment: @H2CO3 If I can guarantee that my destination is large enough to store the string (eg. I have subtracted `s` from `p` in your above examples, and the result is less than `sizeof dest`), then why would I want to use `strncpy`?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Then you don't, but I'm sure OP didn't make such a consideration.

Answer (score 2):

> should I use scanf? getchar? fgets?

Any of the above, but your `while` loop should translate to: while input is read, and the input isn't "exit". Your `while` loop currently translates to: while the world doesn't end.

I suggest something like:

```
while (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin) == s && strcmp(s, "exit\n") != 0) {
    /* ... */
}
```

---

> do I need manually put "\0" ?

No; careful selection of tools allows you to operate upon strings produced by the standard I/O library (in the case of the `fgets`/`strcmp` code above) using the standard string library, or upon non-strings by other more complex means.

---

PS. There is no need to cast `malloc`, and `sizeof (char)` is *always* one in C.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, `fgets()` automatically appends a `\0`.

From [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

`A terminating null character is automatically appended after the characters copied to str.`

Do note that `fgets()` stops reading at the press of Enter and appends a `\n` too, but, from your question, I gather that this might be favourable to you.

For the differences between `fgets()` and `scanf()`, a good discussion can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252132/difference-between-scanf-and-fgets).

Comment: @user1386966 Please don't leave the same comment under each answer. It's considered littering.

Comment: I get it that @H2CO3 already answered your question. It would be good if the discussions are centered in one area. Increases the readability ease for people visiting this thread in the future.