# C scanf with spaces problem

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

printf("please key in book title\n"); 
    scanf("%s",bookname);

i inside the data like this :-
C Programming

but why output the data like this :-
C

lose the Programming (strings) ?

why

thanks.

Answer (score 20):

The `%s` conversion specifier causes `scanf` to stop at the first whitespace character.  If you need to be able to read whitespace characters, you will either need to use the `%[` conversion specifier, such as

```
 scanf("%[^\n]", bookname);
```

which will read everything up to the next newline character and store it to `bookname`, although to be safe you should specify the maximum length of bookname in the conversion specifier; e.g. if bookname has room for 30 characters counting the null terminator, you should write

```
 scanf("%29[^\n]", bookname);
```

Otherwise, you could use `fgets()`:

```
 fgets(bookname, sizeof bookname, stdin);
```

I prefer the `fgets()` solution, personally.

Comment: very thanks. good information :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) instead of `scanf()`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is "why".

Answer (score 0):

Well `bookname` surly is some kind of char ;-)
Point is that `scanf` in this form stop on the first whitespace character.

You can use a different format string, but in this case, one probably should prefer using `fgets`.

`scanf` really should be used for "formatted" input.