# How to accept input with ints and strings with spaces?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to accept input from a file. This file is in the format of an integer, followed by a tab, followed by a string (which may or may not have spaces).

for example:

```
1\tls -l
2\tls
```

I tried using:

```
int   cmd_num;
char command[80];

while (fscanf(ifp, "%d\t%s", &cmd_num, command) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

However, this failed when it saw a space. Any help?

Comment: I didn't understand _this failed when it saw a space_ is it reading 1\tls

Comment: This works when none of the strings had spaces. However, when a string had a space it went into an infinite loop.

Comment: can you post a failing file input?

Comment: So if I had this in the loop "printf("%d\t%s\n", cmd_num, command);" it would output the line "1\tls\n" to infinity.

Comment: ***To those voting to close*** — This is a frequently encountered problem and is not too localized.  If you can find a duplicate (I'm sure there are some), then by all means close it as a duplicate.  But it is not too localized.

Comment: Possible duplicates include: [C `scanf` with spaces problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358383/c-scanf-with-spaces-problem), [How do you allow spaces to be entered using `scanf`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf), and [Reading string with spaces using `scanf()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306303/reading-string-with-spaces-using-scanf).  The earliest of these is SO 1247989 and should probably be given precedence.  I doubt this list is exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use a scan-set to read the string:

```
if (fscanf(fp, "%d\t%79[^\n]\n", &cmd_num, command) != 2)
    ...error handling...
else
    ...use cmd_num and command...
```

Note the size constraint in the format string to prevent buffer overflow.

Note, too, that you will not know whether the newline is matched.  You might be better off using `fgets()` to read the whole line (or `getline()`), and then using `sscanf()` instead of `fscanf()`; at least you'll know whether the newline was collected (and can gobble to the newline if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `fscanf` function:

```
fscanf(fp,"%d\t%[^\n]s",&cmd_num,command);
```

This will surely work...

Comment: You don't need the `s` with a scan-set.  Mind you, it would not actually cause problems, but that's only because it is after the last conversion in the format string and you can't detect when there are mismatches there.