# Opening a file with a title including int and char variables

Tags: c

I want to open a file with the title e.g. "File 10-9B-g06.dat" where "B" and "File" are repeated for all files but the rest are variable. The problem start when I have the "g" in the title. I used the "g" variable as a string, but it did not work as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 int CaseSize, Type, Counter;
 char name[100], zahl[20], char Template[1];

FILE *stream;

scanf("%d", &CaseSize );
scanf("%d", &Type );
scanf("  %c", &Template );
scanf("%d", &Counter );

strcpy(name, "File ");
sprintf(zahl, "%d", CaseSize);
strcat(name, zahl);
strcat(name, "-");
sprintf(zahl, "%d", Type);
strcat(name, zahl);
strcat(name, "B-");
sprintf(name, "%c", Template);
strcat(name, zahl);

sprintf(zahl, "%2d", Counter);
strcat(name, zahl);
strcat(name, ".dat");
stream=fopen(name, "a");

fclose(stream);
return 0;
}
```

I was wondering if anyone can help explain this to me or if they can direct me to anywhere I can get some examples I can look through.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The code has a number of issues with format specifiers and data types, but apart from that is remarkably inefficient and unnecessarily complex.

Changing `char Template[1]` to just `char Template`, and removing the redundant `zahl[]`, the 12 lines you have for constructing `name` can be reduced to just:

```
sprintf( name, "%s %d-%dB-%c%02d.dat", "File", CaseSize, Type, Template, Counter ) ;
```

One problem with C strings is that they contain no length information, so functions such as `strcat()` must iterate from the beginning searching for the nul terminator; here you are using `strcat()` repeatedly on an increasingly long string.  In this short string construction, thus is perhaps not significant, but in some cases it can become [prohibitively slow](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).  Apart from that, more lines of code simply mean more code to maintain and debug. Here the entire format is described in one line of code, so it is mich easier in maintenance to see what it is that should be constructed.

Comment: Thank you very much Clifford! it was really helpful and it seems, I should learn much much more about programing.

Answer (score 0):

First problem seems to be that you're using spaces in scanf when reading variable Template.
See hints here: [C scanf with spaces problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358383/c-scanf-with-spaces-problem)

Comment: The use of spaces here seems to be intentional.

Comment: But is there a purpose of using more than one?

Comment: Two have the same effect as one, so no

Answer (score 0):

The two main problems are these:

> scanf("  %c", &Template );

should be

```
scanf("  %c", &Template[0]);
```

> sprintf(name, "%c", Template);

should be

```
sprintf(zahl, "%c", Template[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Been testing a little, this works:

```
int main()
{
  int CaseSize, Type, Counter;
  char name[100];
  char zahl[20];
  char Template;

  FILE *stream;

  scanf("%d", &CaseSize);
  scanf("%d", &Type);
  scanf(" %c", &Template);
  scanf("%2d", &Counter);

  strcpy(name, "File ");
  sprintf(zahl, "%d", CaseSize);
  strcat(name, zahl);
  strcat(name, "-");
  sprintf(zahl, "%d", Type);
  strcat(name, zahl);
  strcat(name, "B-");
  sprintf(zahl, "%c", Template);
  strcat(name, zahl);

  sprintf(zahl, "%02d", Counter);
  strcat(name, zahl);
  strcat(name, ".dat");
  printf("%s\n", name);
  stream=fopen(name, "a");
  fclose(stream);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all that in a single `sprintf` statement:

```
sprintf( name, "File %d-%dB-%c%02d.dat", CaseSize, Type, Template, Counter );
```

Given how you're using `Template`, you should not declare it as a 1-element array of `char`; the types of the expressions `&Template` and `Template` will be `char (*)[1]` and `char *` respectively, which is not what you want.  Declare it as a plain `char` instead.