# How to input a string using scanf in c including whitespaces

Tags: c

Example if user enters:

`My name is James.`

Using scanf, I have to print the full line, i.e. `My name is James.`, then I have to get the length of this entered string and store it in an `int` variable.

Comment: In real life you would simply use `fgets`.

Comment: In real life you would also use google. [Exact duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
scanf("%80[^\r\n]", string);
```

Replace 80 with 1 less that the size of your array.   [Check out the scanf man page for more information](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/)

Comment: `"%80[^\n]"` should be sufficient, since a `FILE *` opened in text mode (like `stdin`) will convert Windows/whatever newlines to the `\n` character.

Answer (score 3):

[@Splat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054414/how-to-input-a-string-using-scanf-in-c-including-whitespaces/5054550#5054550) has the best answer here, since this is homework and part of your assignment is to use `scanf`. However, `fgets` is much easier to use and offers finer control.

As to your second question, you get the length of a string with `strlen`, and you store it in a variable of type `size_t`. Storing it in an `int` is wrong, because we don't expect to have strings of -5 length. Likewise, storing it in an `unsigned int` or other unsigned type is inappropriate because we don't know exactly how big an integral type is, nor exactly how much room we need to store the size. The `size_t` type exists as a type that is guaranteed to be the right size for your system.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"

void main()
{
char str[20];
int i;
clrscr();
printf("Enter your string");
scanf("%[^\t\n]s",str); --scanf to accept multi-word string
i = strlen(str); -- variable i to store length of entered string
printf("%s %d",str,i); -- display the entered string and length of string
getch();

}

output :

enter your string : My name is james
display output : My name is james 16
```

Comment: `void main()` ? It's 2011. And what do you need to `clrscr()` for?

Comment: ^^ i executed this prgram in TURBO C that's why it it so

Answer (score -1):

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
    char str[20];
    int i,t;
    scanf("%d",&t); 
    while(t--){
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(" %[^\t\n]s",str);// --scanf to accept multi-word string
        i = strlen(str);// -- variable i to store length of entered string
        printf("%s %d\n",str,i);// -- display the entered string and length of string
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DaV this link has a complete details about fflush https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-fflushstdin-c/