# Find string length using strlen and a function. print with empty string

Tags: c

So I am writing this code to print string length of any string I input and I basically have the code already working but I am having trouble because when I enter a blank string my program doesn't print  to screen correctly. It works with a space(spacebar) and all other strings but I must be able to enter an empty string. we are supposed to use something like:
 buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
to enter and print empty strings,
but I am not sure how to enter it in the code correctly. Any ideas??

here is my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int *MyStrlen(const char *string2);

int main()
{
char string2[100];

printf("Enter a string: \n");
scanf("%100[^\n]",&string2);

int  length, length2;

length =  strlen(string2);
length2 = MyStrlen(string2);

printf("strlen(''%s'') returned %d\n", &string2, length);
printf("MyStrlen(''%s'') returned %d\n", &string2, length2);

return 0;
}
```

also, here is MyStrlen function, All works correctly besides entering empty string.

```
int *MyStrlen(const char *string2)
{
int stringcount=0;

while (string2[stringcount]!='\0')
{
    stringcount++;
}
return stringcount;
}
```

Comment: How are you inputting an empty string? And what result exactly do you get?

Comment: 'when I enter a blank string my program doesn't print to screen correctly' - what does it do?

Comment: Well, this is weird: I run the program online [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) and I get perfect output even for blank string, but when I run it my terminal on Ubuntu 14.04 using `gcc`, I get totally wrong output.

Comment: I have been instructed to use something in the sense of buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0'; but it gives me nothing relavant. It runs until 111 letters and is a bunch of different symbols([|[][[)

Comment: Why is `MyStrlen` returning `int *` instead of `int`? Didn't the compiler emit some warnings for that?

Comment: Enter a string:

strlen(''╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠┌>9┘£√▬'') returned 111
MyStrlen(''╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠┌>9┘£√▬'') returned 111
Press any key to continue . . . this is my output. when I enter any other character except a blank It works

Comment: OK, null-terminator,  next..

Comment: all of the `&string2` in main should be `string2`

Comment: did it. Still didin't change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the problem could be corrected with:

Initilize the first element of string2 to `'\0'` before the `scanf`:

`string2[0] = '\0';`

Change the return type of `int *MyStrlen(...)` to `int`:

`int MyStrlen(const char *string2);`

As this post: [How to input a string using scanf in c including whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054414/how-to-input-a-string-using-scanf-in-c-including-whitespaces),
a safer way is to specify a size 1 less than the size of `string2` buffer:

```
scanf("%99[^\r\n]", &string2[0]);
```

Check out the [scanf man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) for more information.

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int MyStrlen(const char *string2);

// change the return type to int
int MyStrlen(const char *string2)
{
    int stringcount=0;

    while (string2[stringcount] != '\0')
        stringcount++;
    return stringcount;
}
int main()
{
    char string2[100];

    // Initialize the first element to 0
    string2[0] = '\0';
    printf("Enter a string: \n");

    scanf("%99[^\r\n]", &string2[0]);

    int  length, length2;


    length =  strlen(string2);
    length2 = MyStrlen(string2);

    // Change to &string2 to string2
    printf("strlen(''%s'') returned %d\n", string2, length);
    printf("MyStrlen(''%s'') returned %d\n", string2, length2);

    return 0;
}
```

The output with empty string:

```
Enter a string:

strlen('''') returned 0
MyStrlen('''') returned 0
```

The output with "aaa":

```
Enter a string:
aaa
strlen(''aaa'') returned 3
MyStrlen(''aaa'') returned 3
```

Comment: this exact code is not working for me. It is still giving me the same output.

Comment: @Cboehm change the scanf line to `if ( 1 != scanf("%100[^\n]", &string2[0]) ) { string2[0] = 0; }`

Comment: Tks @M.M :) @Cboehm I'm using `MinGW-64 gcc` on Windows to make the test. Which compiler are you using? Does it work now?

Comment: I am using Visual studios and not necessarily still testing. @Gomiero

Answer (score -1):

Well, the problem is with

```
scanf("%100[^\n]",&string2);
```

Change it to

```
fgets (string2, 100, stdin);
```

Because that `scanf` cannot read a blank string.

Also, as mentioned in @M.M's comment, check for '\n':

```
int last = strlen (string2) -1;
if (string2 [last] = '\n') {
   string2 [last] = '\0';
}
```

[image]

In the second case I entered a blank string.

The completely corrected code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int *MyStrlen(const char *string2);

// change the rerturn type to int
int *MyStrlen(const char *string2)
{
    int stringcount=0;

    while (string2[stringcount] != '\0')
        stringcount++;
    return stringcount;
}
int main()
{
    char string2[100];

    // Initialize the first element to 0
    string2[0] = '\0';
    printf("Enter a string: \n");
    fgets (string2, 100, stdin);
    int  length, length2;
    int last = strlen (string2) -1;
    if (string2 [last] = '\n') {
       string2 [last] = '\0';
    }


    length =  strlen(string2);
    length2 = MyStrlen(string2);

    printf("strlen(''%s'') returned %d\n", string2, length);
    printf("MyStrlen(''%s'') returned %d\n", string2, length2);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Also as mentioned in @Gomiero's answer, initialize your string to `\0`.

Comment: oh thanks I still get the same output though when I run it.

Comment: Well, i get proper output making these changes. I'll post a screenshot to show you.

Comment: the printf statements have wrong 2nd argument, although you make a good point about the blank string

Comment: @AshishAhuja the `-1` is in the third argument

Comment: @M.M, just got confused, edited. Well, I know that `&` returns address, but it still works with the `&`. Do you know why?

Comment: undefined behaviour can do anything. But you are probably on a system where `&x` and `x` have the same size and representation if `x` is an array. (in general this may not be true)

Comment: The `scanf` should not have `&` either. The `fgets` function does not always append `\n` (e.g. if input overflowed or input closed) so you should really check for the presence of the `\n` and remove it if present, instead of blanket `-1`

Comment: @M.M, will do. Just, for clarification, I have just copied the `scanf`, and will not change it as I am telling the OP not to do that, and instead do the `fgets`.

Comment: I see, that's fine then

Comment: @M.M, is everything alright now. It works completely. Any other mistake? If not, can you please undo the downvote.

Comment: `strlen (string2) -1` is incorrect as the result of strlen may be `0`.  (so, as well as accessing out of bounds on the next line, you have a signed-unsigned mismatch). Also, the line after that should have `==` rather than `=`.