# Sum of n numbers

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int m,i,sum,num;

    i=0;
    sum=0;
    scanf("%d ",&m);
    while(i<m){
        scanf("%d ",&num);

        sum=sum + num;

        i=i+1;
        printf("Value of sum= %d\n",sum);
        //continue;
    }
    printf("Sum= %d ",sum);
}
```

In the above code it should display the sum of n numbers. But in my code it is taking one extra value of m (m is number of values to take to compute the sum).

For example if I take m as 3 it takes 4 input and displays the sum of 3.

Comment: `scanf("%d ",&num);` --> `scanf("%d",&num);`

Comment: Yes, get rid of the spaces in your two scanf's

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I think you should post this as answer

Comment: use `fflushall() ` to clear all input buffers first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others(@BLUEPIXY and @BillDoomProg) have already pointed in the comments, your problem is the space in your `scanf` format string. Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582322/what-does-space-in-scanf-mean).

Change both your `scanf` format string from:

```
scanf("%d ",&m);
...
scanf("%d ",&num);
```

To:

```
scanf("%d", &m);
...
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Just remove the space and it will work fine.

## scanf()

#### From the manual

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives(...)
>
> A directive is one of the following:
>
> A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see
>   isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of white space, including 
>   none, in the input.

Also note that `stdin` is buffered, so the results are a little different from what you would expect:

```
man stdin
```

> ### Notes
>
> The stream *stderr* is unbuffered. The stream *stdout* is line-buffered when 
>   it points to a terminal. Partial lines will not appear until fflush(3) or 
>   exit(3) is called, or a newline is printed. This can produce unexpected 
>   results, especially with debugging output. The buffering mode of the 
>   standard streams (or any other stream) can be changed using the setbuf(3) 
>   or setvbuf(3) call. Note that in case **stdin is associated with a terminal, 
>   there may also be input buffering in the terminal driver, entirely 
>   unrelated to stdio buffering**. (Indeed, normally terminal input is line 
>   buffered in the kernel.) This kernel input handling can be modified using 
>   calls like tcsetattr(3); see also stty(1), and termios(3).

## So, lets examine your program step by step.

*Your program starts running and you enter the number 2. This is what the input buffer looks like:*

```
2\n
```

`scanf("%d ", &m)` assigns 2 to the `m` variable and starts trying to match a space. It gets a `NL` and `EOL`. Control is still with this `scanf` because it just matched a newline (considered a white-space) and is waiting to match more, but instead it got the `End-Of-Line`, so it is still waiting when you type:

```
1\n
```

Then reads **stdin** again and realizes that the next character in the input stream is not a space and returns (it's format string condition was done). At this point, you **enter the loop** and your next `scanf("%d ",&num)` is called and it wants to read an integer, *which it does*: it reads 1 and stores that in the `num` variable.  Then again it starts matching white-spaces and gets the new-line and it repeats the above pattern. Then when you enter:

```
2\n
```

That second `scanf` gets a character different than a white-space
and returns, so your loop scope keeps executing printing the current `sum`.
The loop break condition is not met, so it starts again. It calls the
`scanf` and it effectively reads an integer into the variable, then the
pattern repeats itself...

```
3\n
```

It was waiting for a white-space but it got a character instead. So your
`scanf` returns **and now the loop break condition is met**. This is where you exit your loop, prints the whole `sum` and get that *weired felling that it
"added" 3 numbers but the sum is adding only the first 2* (as you intended
in the first place).

You can check that 3 hanging in **stdin** with a simple addition to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{

    int m, i, sum, num;
    char c;

    i = 0;
    sum = 0;
    scanf("%d ", &m);

    while (i < m) {
        scanf("%d ", &num);

        sum = sum + num;

        i = i + 1;
        printf("Value of sum= %d\n", sum);
    }

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n') 
        printf("Still in buffer: %c", c);

    return 0;
}
```

That will output (with the above input, of couse):

```
$ ./sum1
2
1
2
Value of sum= 1
3
Value of sum= 3
Still in buffer: 3
```

Comment: Your answer was very useful . I wanna ask you about deep learning when it comes to C. I have just started learning C and i wanna get into the mood of deep learning.How should i do it? I m taking the help of video tutorials.

Comment: Learning each and everything from the scratch.  Trying to know everything that is to be known about C.

Comment: @AryanRagavan Read the [K&R Book](http://tiny.cc/5ruv2x) then jump to [this site](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/). The thing with C is that it's a fairly **simple** language and shouldn't take you long to get how it works. But C was designed to build operating systems: that means you should understand how **computers work** in order to use it's full power. A good starting point on that is the excellent book (**WARNING PDF**) [Programming from the Ground Up](http://download-mirror.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf), which will also teach you some Assembly.

Comment: @AryanRagavan As for video tutorials, I can't help you. I never watched any introductory C video lectures, so I can't point good one. On some good stuff though, [Rusty Russel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rusty_Russell) has some pretty nice videos on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=rusty+russell).

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have a space after your `%d` in the `scanf` lines.

**Change**

```
scanf("%d ",&num);
```

**To**

```
scanf("%d",&num);
```

`Scanf` usually ignores whitespaces, so you don't want spaces in your format strings.

Answer (score 0):

It's causes of `extra space in scanf()`. Change `scanf("%d ",&num) to scanf("%d",&num)`

From [Scanf(), fscanf()](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/scanf.html), You can follow this.

> The scanf() family of functions reads data from the console or from a
>   FILE stream, parses it, and stores the results away in variables you
>   provide in the argument list.
>
> The format string is very similar to that in printf() in that you can
>   tell it to read a "%d", for instance for an int. But it also has
>   additional capabilities, most notably that it can eat up other
>   characters in the input that you specify in the format string.

You should write:

```
int main()
{
    int m,i,sum,num;

    i=0;
    sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&m);
    while(i<m){
        scanf("%d",&num);

        sum=sum + num;

        i=i+1;
        printf("Value of sum= %d\n",sum);
        //continue;
    }
    printf("Sum= %d ",sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A refactored code will look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int m, num, sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &m);    // Let scanf automatically skip whitespace
    while (m--) {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        sum += num;
    }
    printf("Sum= %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```