# while loop working improperly/unexpectedly?

Tags: c

So I have this code:

```
char inputs[10] = "";
int numInputs = 0;
while (numInputs < 10){
    char c;
    printf("Enter char %i: ",numInputs);
    scanf("%c",&c);
    numInputs++;
}
```

I'm just trying to fill the array with 10 char values as inputted by the user. When i run this, it only lets me enter inputs ever other loop (?). This is what the console looks like-

`Enter char 0: c
Enter char 1: Enter char 2: r
Enter char 3: Enter char 4: r
Enter char 5: Enter char 6: r
Enter char 7: Enter char 8: r
Enter char 9: Program ended with exit code: 0`

Is there a nit-picky thing here that i'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does space in scanf mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582322/what-does-space-in-scanf-mean)

Comment: You should learn how to debug your code. Here's a good intro: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
scanf ("%c", &c);
```

to

```
scanf (" %c", &c);
```

As @haris mentioned, the space is used to consume the `\n` (newline) left in the input buffer caused by the previous `scanf`.

Also see: [What does space in scanf mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582322/what-does-space-in-scanf-mean)

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Why exactly is the extra space required?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it's because you added the extra space? Try changing `printf("Enter char %i: ",numInputs);` to `printf("Enter char %i:",numInputs);` . It may be hard to see, but after %i: it seems you have a space that scanf() is reading?

Comment: @Jordan, space is used to consume the left out newline character `\n` in the input buffer after the previous `scanf`s.

Comment: @Haris, would you typically then just scan a newline character instead? Something like `scanf ("%c\n", &c);`? EDIT: Disregard, saw other answer just come in.

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work fine. scanf waits for input on a new line. Since you were not returning to a new line it was reading already existing space character on the current line.

```
 char inputs[10] = "";
    int numInputs = 0;
    char c;
    while (numInputs < 10){
        printf("Enter char %i: ",numInputs);
        scanf("%c\n",&c);
        numInputs++;
    }
```