# Exit with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, exit, exit-code

Ok so i am working on some school work in Visual Studio 2015 for the first time and my program will not go into an if statements and just exits with code 0, i tried removing the if statement and it works but I need to have it.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    char c1, c2;
    int controlPoint;
    int counter, counterTwo;
    float intSingle;
    int isTrue = 0;
    float* x;
    float* y;
    float* fx;
    float sum = 0;
    float temp;
    int k;



    printf(" \n Please select an option");
    printf(" \n Press i to do an interlopation");
    printf(" \n Press q to quit");

    scanf("%c", &c1);


    if (c1 == 'q' || c1 == 'Q') {
        printf("Now Quiting");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (c1 == 'i' || c1 == 'I') {
        printf(" \n Do a Lagrange Interlopation");
        printf(" \n How many control points are there?");

        scanf("%d", &controlPoint);
        x = malloc(controlPoint * sizeof(float));
        y = malloc(controlPoint * sizeof(float));

        for (counter = 0; counter < controlPoint; counter++) {
            printf("Please Enter the x coordinate for control point #%d: ", counter);
            scanf("%f", &x[counter]);
            printf("Please Enter the y coordinate for control point #%d: ", counter);
            scanf("%f", &y[counter]);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid Option Quitting");

    }









    printf("\nPlease select an option");
    printf("\n Press s to do single interlopation");
    printf("\n Press r to interlope in increments over the entire range");
    printf("\n Press q to quit");

    scanf("%c", &c2);

    if (c2 == 's' || c2 == 'S') {
        printf(" \n Interlope Single");
        printf(" \n Please enter the value of x you wish to interlope for: ");
        scanf("%f", &intSingle);
        fx = malloc(controlPoint * sizeof(float));

        for (counter = 0; counter < controlPoint; counter++)
        {
            temp = 1;
            int k = counter;

            for (counterTwo = 0; counterTwo < controlPoint; counterTwo++)
            {
                if (k == counterTwo)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    temp = temp * ((intSingle - x[counterTwo]) / (x[k] - x[counterTwo]));
                }
            }
            fx[counter] = y[counter] * temp;

        }

        for (counter = 0; counter < controlPoint; counter++)
        {
            sum = sum + fx[counter];
        }
        printf("\n Interpolated pair is (%f, %f) ", intSingle, sum);
    }

    else if (c2 == 'q' || c2 == 'Q'){
        printf("Now Quiting");
        exit(0);

    }
    int holder;

    scanf("%d", &holder);



}
```

the problem is when user inputs second option, it just closes if i press s with code 0 i also removed the if statement and the code works fine but i need them

Comment: Have you considered stepping through your code in the debugger?  Not sure which if statement you're referring to or what your input is.  Perhaps you could clarify those things.

Comment: when the code reaches here if (c2 == 's' || c2 == 'S') {

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582322/what-does-space-in-scanf-mean

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 3):

First, your code doesnt look very good, you are not freeing dynamic allocation, some missing `\n`, etc..

For your question, 
`scanf %c` read only one char, when you type a letter and press enter you actaully type `i\n`.

The first `scanf` read the letter `i`, but `\n` stays in the buffer, until the next `scanf` reads it instead of `s`.

You can use something like this to clear the `stdin` buffer:

`while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n' && temp != EOF);`

Or, if you are sure your input is only 1 char, you can just add space before `%c` to ignore `\n`: 
`scanf("%c",...`
to
`scanf(" %c",...`

Comment: Putting a space before `%c` in the format string will also skip whitespace.

Comment: Agreed, will add