# Why is the following C code asking input twice?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, input, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i, j;
  for(scanf("%d ",&i); i<=10; i++)
    printf("%d ",i);
  return 0;
}
```

I am a beginner in the programming world so please help me understand why on compiling the above C code it asks inputs twice.Maybe there's some logic to loop here I might be missing. Please help me understand.Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: `scanf("%d ",&i);` --> `scanf("%d", &i);`

Comment: So what's with the space?.Why should it prompt me once again for input? Please give reason

Comment: I cannot see in the code it asking for anything

Comment: Perhaps read the manual page

Comment: scanf in loop asks for input

Comment: The space means it will try to read the space, so you're reading a number and a space, not just a number

Comment: The space I was giving in scanf was prompting me to take input twice...But still I need an explanation why a space in scanf () would prompt me 2wice for input

Comment: It does not ask for anything. It just waits for input. That aside it is a good to get familiar with the manual pages

Comment: In the `scanf` format string, the space character skips the space character from the input and waits for non-space characters to be entered.

Comment: @user7841468 I just answered. ^

Comment: @EdHeal: Whether "*waiting*" is taken as "*asking*" might be cultural decision, question, issue, ...

Comment: Thank you everyonefor such active responses. I appreciate you all for the help....Keep doing the good work

Comment: Duplicate of "trailing white space in scanf format string is evil", which is related to what the linked question covers, but there are other questions and answers which deal explicitly with trailing white space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
scanf("%d ",&i);
```

to this:

```
scanf("%d",&i);
```

Read more in [What does space in scanf mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582322/what-does-space-in-scanf-mean)

Comment: Thanks ..This is a very common mistake ...Now I know what was happening ...Thank you very much sir ... :)

Comment: @user7841468 Better: don't use scanf at all. Always get input a line at a time (posix `getline`, or implement it yourself as a loop around `fgets`), and *then* parse it (possibly using `sscanf`)

Answer (score 0):

Currencly, you placed scanf() in a for loop, which it asks for input for a 10 times.This will not happen when you remove scanf() from for loop.

Comment: `scanf()` is in the initialization part of the `for` loop. It'll only run once.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and the only change I did was to change "%d  " to "%d". This solves the problem.