# C program terminates before accepting scanf() input

Tags: c, input, scanf

Although I understand the layout of this program is wierd, I think my program is having trouble when it comes to the `scanf()` line. For some reason after the `metricConversion()` function is entered. The `scanf()` line is printed but the program exits and terminates before an input is given... I am not understanding why this happens...

```
#include <stdio.h>

char inputtedChar;
int inputtedInt;

int metricConversion(){
    scanf("Press K for conversion from Kelvin to Celsius %c", &inputtedChar);

    if(inputtedChar == 'K'){
        //do Something
    } else { return 0; }
}

int main() {
    printf("Press 0 to enter conversion function!");
    scanf("%d", &inputtedInt);

    if (inputtedInt == 0) {
        metricConversion();
    }
}
```

More importantly, can someone explains why `scanf()` works the way it does? And what the best alternatives are so I dont run into this again?

Comment: Are you sure that `scanf()` line is printed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `scanf("Press K for conversion from Kelvin to Celsius %c", &inputtedChar);` to:

```
printf("Press K for conversion from Kelvin to Celsius ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf(" %c", &inputtedChar);
/*     ^                    */
/*   this space             */
```

There were 2 problems. Use `printf` for prompt. And you need to use space in `scanf` to ignore whitespace before a `%c`, `%[…]` (scan set) or `%n` conversion. Using `fflush` will ensure that the prompt is printed on screen before it waits for input.

It is advisable to use an `fflush` before `scanf` in `main` function also unless you want to terminate printed string with a `'\n'`.

---

> What does `scanf("Press K for conversion from Kelvin to Celsius %c", &inputtedChar);` mean?

This doesn't print anything. It means program expects exact input `Press K for conversion from Kelvin to Celsius <SOME_CHAR>` and reads `<SOME_CHAR>` in input. For more details you need to understand the regex.

Comment: *There were 2 problems.*  **Three** problems - the return value from `scanf()` is never checked to make sure something is actually read from the console.

Comment: Thanks so much! So why does the space make such a big difference? As a new C programmer, I wouldnt even know where to start looking to solve such a small problem...

Comment: @CosmicCat [Space makes a difference when you are reading a `char` with `%c`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582322/what-does-space-in-scanf-mean) because space is also a `char`. When you specify a space you ask `scanf` to skip every white space character (space, tab, newline etc) and read the first non white space character. Without space you ask for first character that may or may not be a white space. To solve such problems, you can read specifications of functionalities used for ex. `scanf` in this case from man page or good book and solve some toy problems.