# While/Switch Statement weird output

Tags: c++, switch-statement, do-while

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float cost, total;
bool loop(char item){
        switch (toupper(item)) {
            case 'A':
                cost = 4.25;        
                return true;
            case 'B':
                cost = 5.57;
                return true;
            case 'C':
                cost = 5.25;
                return true;
            case 'D':
                cost = 3.75;
                return true;
            case 'T':
                return false;
        }
        return true;
}

int main(){
        char item;
        do {
            printf("\nEnter Item Ordered [A/B/C/D] or T to calculate total:");
            scanf("%c", &item);
            total = total + cost;
        } while (loop(item)); 
        printf("Total Cost: $%f\n", total);
}
```

Let me output the process:

```
$ ./Case3.o 

Enter Item Ordered [A/B/C/D] or T to calculate total:a

Enter Item Ordered [A/B/C/D] or T to calculate total:
Enter Item Ordered [A/B/C/D] or T to calculate total:b

Enter Item Ordered [A/B/C/D] or T to calculate total:
Enter Item Ordered [A/B/C/D] or T to calculate total:a

Enter Item Ordered [A/B/C/D] or T to calculate total:
Enter Item Ordered [A/B/C/D] or T to calculate total:t
Total Cost: $28.139999
```

Why is it after the first printf its printing the `printf` twice but skipping me from input the first time. then how is it calculating 5.24+5.57+5.24 to equal 28.14?

Comment: If it is C++, use `cout` to write output to stream and `cin` to take input.

Comment: The newline character in your input is the reason. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf

Comment: printf makes me feel fancy...

Comment: fixed with `scanf("%c%*c", &item);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, When you press Enter, two characters get inputted, `the character you enter + the newline`, You need to account for both of these.

Possible solutions are:

**Approach 1: The C way**

```
 scanf(" %c", &item);
       ^^^
```

Add a space here, or the better approach,

**Approach 2: The C++ way**

simply use the C++ way of getting input from user.

```
cin >> item;
```

**Why the result is Undefined?**
<strike>Because you did not initialize the variable `total`, This results in **Undefined Behavior** giving you unexpected output.</strike>
`total` is a global so it will be **Default Initialized** to 0.0.
Real reason for Undefined result is in @Mystical's answer.

Comment: I can just use `scanf("%c%*c", &item);` Thanks though

Comment: @JohnRiselvato: Indeed,Important is to understand `why?` part of it and then there can be `n` solutions, Glad you could understand :)

Comment: Hopefully someone can come back to this one day and find your solutions helpful. Cheers

Comment: No, @John, seriously. Either be a C programmer or a C++ programmer. There is no middle ground :-)

Comment: hmmm... is that unethical in the programming world or something? haha. Can we meet in a chat and discuss this @paxdiablo

Comment: @JohnRiselvato: You can be C and C++ programmer both but dont use C in C++, they both serve and are designed for inherently different purposes.

Answer (score 3):

`enter` is a keystroke - you need to account for it :)

<strike>As for your math, you never initialize `total` to `0` therefore the initial value is indeterminate.</strike>

Wasn't paying attention to the scoping - the real answer for the math is that the loop re-adds the previous cost when `enter` is pressed. This is noted in Mysticial's answer.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right about the indeterminate `total`? In C at least, static variables are initialised to zero. Is that not the same in C++?

Comment: Yeah - I wasn't paying attention to the scoping. The real answer is as detailed in another answer, it re-adds the last `cost`

Answer (score 1):

This is easily explained. When you enter `a` and hit the `ENTER` key, this places *two* characters in the input buffer, the `a` and the `newline` character.

That's why, for all but the first, you have a spurious prompt since it prints it and then gets the `newline` from standard input.

`scanf` is really a C compatibility thing in C++, you should be using `cin >> something` (or *any* of the streams-related stuff really) for C++-style input.

This double hit of charcaters also explains the errant total as well since, when you *get* that `newline` in, you add the current value of cost *again* in your main loop.

Your total is composed of two of each value due to the fact that you're adding `cost` regardless of the value entered.

With your entry of `a,b,a`, that would be `4.25 + 5.57 + 4.25 = 14.07` - `a` is `4.25`, not `5.24`. And `28.14` is exactly twice `14.07`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `newline` has been mentioned, I'll answer the other question of why `28.14`.

Notice that in your switch, the default is just return. `cost` is never set. Therefore, when it reads in the `newline` it skips the switch block and leaves cost untouched.

So the result is this:

```
total = 0;  // It's actually undefined since you didn't initialize, but it probably started as zero.

total += 4.25;    //  For a
total += 4.25;    //  For '\n' after the 'a'

total += 5.57;    //  For b
total += 5.57;    //  For '\n' after the 'b'

total += 4.25;    //  For a
total += 4.25;    //  For '\n' after the 'a'
```

Final answer: `28.14`

The `t` that is entered last doesn't get added to `total`.