# Few questions about C syntax

Tags: c, syntax

I have a few questions about C syntax.

1. `ch = (char *) malloc( sizeof( char ) * strlen(src) );`
   What do the first brackets mean (char *) ?
2. `c=getch();`

   `switch(c) {`

   `case '1' :{`

   My teacher asked why 'this type' quotation marks are used and not "double". I said that it is C syntax if using char variable. But he said NO! Why are single quotation marks used and not double?
3. Sometimes when using `scanf` nothing happens and it has be used two times to get something scanned. What is the reason of this problem?
   For example:

   ```
   printf("enter string \n");   
   scanf("%s",&str);
   printf("enter char \n");  
   scanf("%c",&ch);  //does not scan my char
   scanf("%c",&ch);  //with this second line do scan my char
   ```

Comment: Please, can you elaborate on your last question? Or yet better would be if you could provide an example for clarification.

Comment: I think [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802540/while-switch-statement-weird-output/) Question has a use case and answer for your last Q.

Comment: You are meant to ask one question at a time: [faq]

Answer (score 13):

Others have already answered yor First two Questions correctly, So I will answer your third Q:

When you enter a `character` and hit the ENTER key, two characters are placed in the input buffer, the `character` and the `newline` character.

You need to account for both of these. So First `scanf` consumes the newline and another reads the character.

**Step by Step Code Analysis:**

```
printf("enter string \n");   
scanf("%s",&str);
```

With above two statements, You see `Enter the string` and program waits for your input.
Let us assume you enter the character `C` and pressed Enter once. When you perform this action, the input buffer receives two characters:

1. The character `C` that you entered &
2. The newline character `\n`

The `scanf` statement reads just one character(`C`) from the input buffer.Thus, the `newline` character remains unread in the Inuput buffer.

```
printf("enter char \n");  
scanf("%c",&ch);  //does not scan my char
```

With above two statements, `enter char` gets displayed but the `scanf` just skips(not wait for any uer input), this is because the unread `newline` character in the Input buffer is read by this `scanf`.

So to appropriately receive the next input character you need an additional `scanf`.

```
scanf("%c",&ch);  //with this second line do scan my char
```

Comment: I'm curious, why does the `scanf` consume the characters in what seems like the reverse order?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:Sorry,I saw this comment quite late(the time diff),Apparantely, my answer was not explanatory,I added a detail step by step to answer your query.

Answer (score 5):

```
ch = (char *) malloc( sizeof( char ) * strlen(src) );
```

The `(char*)` is a cast. It says to treat the return value of `malloc` as a pointer to `char`. However, this is not necessary since `void*`, the return type of `malloc` is assignment compatible with all pointer variables in C.

What's more the `sizeof(char)` is spurious since `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition. Finally this allocation almost certainly allocates one element too few. There needs to be space for the zero terminator.

So, it should probably be written:

```
ch = malloc(strlen(src)+1);
```

---

As for `'1'`, this is a `char` literal. It has type `int`.

This is not too be confused with `"1"` which is a string literal, of type `char*`, a pointer to a block of memory containing two chars, `'1'` followed by `\0`.

---

As for question 3, it's not clear to me what you mean and in any case I will invoke the one question at a time rule to justify not addressing it! Others have answered that for you.

Comment: In C, character literals have type `int`.

Answer (score 4):

In simple terms:

1) since malloc returns a pointer of type void, you are casting that pointer to a pointer of type char so that the variable ch will later hold an array of characters (a string )

2) the single quotation marks are mainly used because a switch statement in C always expects an INTEGER and, not a string. having a character surrounded by single quotations would return the integer representation of the character.

3) This is a common problem when using scanf, basically it is caused by by the carriage return that is entered from the previous scanf. I would recommend that you always flush the input before using it.

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char line[200];
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nenter a string: ");
        fflush(stdout);         // safety flush since no newline in printf above
        scanf(" %[^\n]",line);  // note space character
        printf("you entered >%s<\n",line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. This is cast; it treats the return value of `malloc` (a `void*`) as a `char*`.
2. This is an ordinary `char` literal.

Comment: This is C. The nonstandard function `getch` most likely returns an `int`. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/getch.html

Comment: Actually, `getch` returns an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
char *ch = (char *) malloc( sizeof( char ) * strlen(src) );
```

The first `(char *)` casts the return value to a `char *`. In C, this is completely unnecessary, and [can mask failure to `#include <stdlib.h>`](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html).

In addition, `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so is never needed.

The character literal [`'1'` has type `int` in C](http://c-faq.com/charstring/sizeofchar.html).

Most likely `getch` returns an `int`. The string literal `"1"` consists of two characters. The digit `1` and the end of string marker `NUL` character. If you had used `case "1":` the return value of `getch` would be compared to the value of the pointer to `"1"` (after an implicit conversion to `int`).

As for `scanf`, the input buffer might contain input that hasn't been processed by your program.

See also [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) .

Answer (score 1):

1. The (char *) at the beginning of the first statement is a typecast.  By default malloc returns a void* which should be fine to assign to a char*, but in other cases typecasting is required.
2. You are correct single quotes should be used around charaters.
3. Saying scanf sometimes doesn't work is a meaningless statement without example code.

Answer (score 1):

1. `(char *)` is a *cast*; it means "treat the following value as a pointer to `char`".  In this particular case it's redundant and considered bad practice.
2. '1' is a *character constant*; somewhat non-intuitively, it has type `int` (this is different from C++, where character constants are type `char`).  "1" would be a *string constant*, which is actually an array expression of type `char [2]` and has the contents `{'1', 0}`.
3. This is because a newline has been left in the input stream from the previous input operation.  Suppose you type "foo" and hit Return; the input stream will then contain the characters 'f', 'o', 'o', '\n'.  The first `scanf` call reads and assigns "foo" to `str`, leaving the trailing '\n' in the input stream.  That stray newline is being picked up by the next `scanf` call because the `%c` conversion specifier doesn't skip whitespace (unlike just about every other conversion specifier).

Answer (score 0):

I d like to add to @Alok Save s answer. He has analysed it correctly however, another simple solution exists for that case and that is to use scanf with a whitespace in the string format as follows:

```
scanf(" %c", &variable);
```

This is because %c does not absorb the newline character like others(like %d) do. Any whitespace in the format string will cause scan to absorb all consecutive whitespaces thereby obviating the need for another scanf statement.

Hope this helps!