# Program doesn't wait for user input with scanf("%c",&yn);

Tags: c, scanf, file-pointer

This is the basic code to a program I am writing to practise using files in C. I am trying to detect whether the output file already exists and if it does exist I want to ask the user if they would like to overwrite it or not. This is the reason that I have first opened the outfilename file in with fopen(outfilename,"r"); as opposed to fopen(outfilename,"w");.

It detects the case of the file not existing, however, if it does exist it executes the printf("Output file already exists, overwrite (y/n):"); statement but completely ignores the scanf("%c",&yn); statement!

The printf at the end of the program reads "yn=0" if the file doesn't exist and just "yn=" if it does exist. Can anybody help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *inf;
    FILE *outf;
    char filename[21],outfilename[21];
    char yn='0';

    printf("Please enter an input filename: ");
    scanf("%s",&filename);

    printf("Please enter an output filename: ");    
    scanf("%s",&outfilename);

    /* Open file for reading */
    inf=fopen (filename,"r");
    outf=fopen(outfilename,"r");

    /*check that input file exists*/
    if (inf!=NULL) {

        /*check that the output file doesn't already exist*/
        if (outf==NULL){
            fclose(outf);
            /*if it doesn't already exist create file by opening in "write" mode*/
            outf=fopen(outfilename,"w");
        } else {
            /*If the file does exist, give the option to overwrite or not*/
            printf("Output file already exists, overwrite (y/n):");
            scanf("%c",&yn);
        }
    }
    printf("\n yn=%c \n",yn);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't `fclose(outf)` if `outf == NULL`. You can't close a file you failed to open in the first place.

Comment: i wasnt sure so i just added it in! not very good pracice i realise!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
printf("Please enter an output filename: ");    
scanf("%s",&outfilename);
```

When you enter the second string and hit the ENTER key, a string and a character are placed in the input buffer, they are namely: the entered string and the newline character.The string gets consumed by the `scanf` but the newline remains in the input buffer.

Further,

```
scanf("%c",&yn);
```

Your next `scanf` for reading the character just reads/consumes the newline and hence never waits for user input.

Solution is to consume the extra newline by using:

```
scanf(" %c", &yn);
      ^^^   <------------Note the space
```

Or by using `getchar()`

You may want to check out my answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7826875/452307)** for a detailed step by step explanation of the problem.

Comment: definitely, I am new to all of this but I understand that the second scanf reads and stores "\nfile.txt" to char outfilename[21] and that the 3rd scanf statement stores the remaining "\n" to char yn that was in the input buffer after I inputted the outfilename. Cheers for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
scanf("%20s",&filename);
```

and remember that *stdin* is line buffered and on Linux is following a [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) discipline

You could use [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) or [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) if you want more detailed control.

Comment: How is that related to the problem at hand?

Comment: Using readline will read a whole line, with editing abilities, which is relevant for reading e.g. the filename and the yn...

Comment: And following the URL link about `tty` is very relevant to the question. It contains a lot of explanations (notably historical) which explains why reading from stdin inside a terminal is so complex....

Comment: wouldn't it be `scanf("%20s",filename);` ?

Answer (score 1):

The better way to handle this problem I found is [explained here](http://home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/c/getting_input.html).

It recomends to use an alternative way of handle input and is very well explained.

I use always this function to get user input.

```
char * read_line (char * buf, size_t length) {
    /**** Copyright de home.datacomm.ch/t_wolf/tw/c/getting_input.html#skip
    Read at most 'length'-1 characters from the file 'f' into
    'buf' and zero-terminate this character sequence. If the
    line contains more characters, discard the rest.
    */
    char *p;
    if ((p = fgets (buf, length, stdin))) {
        size_t last = strlen (buf) - 1;
        if (buf[last] == '\n') {
            /**** Discard the trailing newline */
            buf[last] = '\0';
        } else {
            /**** There's no newline in the buffer, therefore there must be
            more characters on that line: discard them!
            */
            fscanf (stdin, "%*[^\n]");
            /**** And also discard the newline... */
            (void) fgetc (stdin);
        } /* end if */
    } /* end if */
    return p;
} /* end read_line */
```

---

### Old Answer

I fixed this sort of problems with this rule:

```
// first I get what I want.
c = getchar();
// but after any user input I clear the input buffer
// until the \n character:
while (getchar() != '\n');
// this also discard any extra (unexpected) character.
```

If you make this after any input, there should be not problem.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s", ...)` leaves the \n terminating the line in the input.  It isn't causing a problem for the next one as scanf("%s", ...) starts by skipping whites.  `scanf("%c", ...)` doesn't and thus you read the `\n`.

BTW You'll probably meet other problems is you put spaces in your file name (`%s` doesn't read them) and if you enter too long names (%s has no input length limitations).

One solution for the problem you complained (but not the other one) is to use `scanf(" %c", ...)` (see the space before `%c`? `scanf` is tricky to use) which starts by skipping white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s",&filename);
```

also remove the &

scanf.c:13: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[20u]'

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your answer