# C setting variable value to \n

Tags: c, variables, conditional-statements, newline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Program doesn’t wait for user input with scanf(“%c”,&yn);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464620/program-doesnt-wait-for-user-input-with-scanfc-yn)

I've just started programming in C, and something strange (which I didn't encounter in C++) is popping up.

In my header file, I declare a variable (see `onemoretime` in code for `.h` file), whose value is later set using user input through `scanf()`. For some reason, the conditionals which use the variable wouldn't work properly, either returning an infinitely repeating result, or just not doing anything. I set some breakpoints, and found that the first time `onemoretime` is called in the `main()` function, the value of `onemoretime` is, for some reason, set to `\n`.

This isn't a value `scanf()` is supposed to recognize, but the input is treated like a new line (obviously). When I enter `y`, which should trigger the `else if` conditional and loop back to the beginning of `main()`, Xcode's debugger simply says, `error: 'y' is not a valid command.`

Here's my `.h` file:

```
#ifndef C1_Header_h
#define C1_Header_h

float num1, num2;
char op, onemoretime;

#endif
```

... And here's the relevant code from the `.c` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Header.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Enter a two-number calculation below:\n");
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%f%c%f", &num1, &op, &num2);

        // addition
        if (op == '+')
        {
            printf("%f\n", num1+num2);
            printf("\nDone. Would you like to solve another math problem (y/n)?\n");
            scanf("%c", &onemoretime);
            while (1)
            {
                if (onemoretime == 'n') 
                {
                    printf("Ok. Terminating program.");
                    return 0;
                }
                else if (onemoretime == 'y') 
                {
                    // loop back to start main function
                }
            }
        }
    }
        // rest of code, irrelevant here
}
```

If it's a factor at all, hovering over the `onemoretime` variable in Xcode (showing its basic properties), every instance of the variable after the initial declaration in the header file shows the value to be `\n`.

What am I doing wrong? How can the value of `onemoretime` be set by the user, rather than being set by the program before the user can get to it?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - two things at first glance: 1 you started with C++ and you're trying to learn C afterwards, 2. you're getting user input using `scanf()`, which in turn doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: What's wrong with learning C alongside C++?

Comment: nC has some concepts that you definitely need to have a grasp on in order not to make mistakes. C++ has these as well, but with a twist, and since C++ is a more complex (and in fact, more difficult-to-get-right) language, I generally encourage people to master C before diving deep into C++ or they'll have problems like this one.

Comment: Just to disagree with H2CO3 - If you want to learn C++ only, there is no reason to learn C first. It will just give you another set of problems when relearning.  If you want to learn any combination of C, C++, C#, and Java, you will have problems with looks-the-same-works-differently whichever order you try to learn them.

Comment: H2CO3: ... and what happens when one finds out that the modulo operator in C++ doesn't act the same as the modulo operator in C, after they've written twenty-thousand lines of code that makes the assumption that they act the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [`\n`] isn't a value `scanf()` is supposed to recognize, […]

That's true in general, but "The normal skip over white-space characters is suppressed in [the case of `%c`]" [[link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fscanf.html)].

To get `op` and `onemoretime`, I'd recommend using `fgetc` ([link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/fgetc.html)) rather than `scanf`, and handling the whitespace-skipping yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to get one single character with `scanf()` you must always use something to absorb the newline character.You could do something like this `scanf("%c\n",&onemoretime);`