# Do while loop not exiting despite expression becoming false

Tags: c, switch-statement, break, do-while

I've got a program here which contains a do-while loop within a specified void method. I'm trying to exit the loop within the function, so that the do-while loop actually works as it is supposed to. Except after I run the program and one of the cases occurs, the program continues to run despite my while statement stating that it should only work while(userInput != 1).
I cannot use global variables to solve this problem, as my assignment limits me on using such techniques, thus any help would be much appreciated!

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
void functionTest()
{
    int gameOver = 0;
    int userInput;

    do
    {
        printf("please enter a number 1-3");
        scanf("%d",&userInput);

        switch(userInput)
        {
            case 1:
               printf("You entered %d",userInput);
               gameOver = 1;
               break;

            case 2:
               printf("You entered %d",userInput);
               gameOver = 1;
               break;

            case 3:
               printf("You entered %d",userInput);
               gameOver = 1;
               break;
        }
    }
    while(gameOver!= 1);
}
}
```

Comment: Why is case written with capital c?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/BRS5rx

Comment: Post the full code, the way it is in your program because this works as intended.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but you have an extra `}` at the end.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. Put a `printf("%d\n", gameOver);` at the end of the while loop and look what is printed. Maybe it's a `scanf` issue. `scanf` reacts strangely when the input format is not respected.

Comment: Unrelated: clcto, I've never seen that site before, I REALLY like that. Always awesome to run into new tools or websites.

Comment: what does the debugger say

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably lies when you use scanf(). Something that you're inputting before hitting enter is not 1, 2 or 3. Could you tell us exactly what you type when it asks you to enter a choice?

Sometimes, the standard output needs to be flushed before using a fresh scanf(). Try fflush(stdout) before the scanf line.
See [older question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464620/program-doesnt-wait-for-user-input-with-scanfc-yn) and [older question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877264/c-c-printf-before-scanf-issue).

EDIT:
I can reproduce the problem easily enough if I enter anything apart from "1","2" or "3"...

I would suggest, you do the following before executing the switch statement:

1. Add fflush(stdout) before scanf()
2. Accept the input as a string (%s) instead of a number. (char [] needed)
3. Trim the string of trailing and leading white spaces.
4. Convert to number using a library function
5. Then switch-case based on that number

Comment: Hard to say without seeing full code but you are probably correct. scanf() can be a heartless beast sometimes :)

Comment: It is easy enough to determine if `scanf` is successfully reading the input: check the return value.

Comment: I agree. The program certainly needs a lot of input verification/massaging before hitting the switch case, but that comes with some more experience than possibly what OP has currently.

Comment: by the way, @clcto, the website you mentioned in the comments above is very useful! Thank you!

Comment: "*Sometimes, the standard output needs to be flushed before using a fresh scanf()*" I doubt this. Why this? And if, why only "*sometimes*"? Out is out and in is in, they aren't coupled.

Comment: A similar problem occurred here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877264/c-c-printf-before-scanf-issue

and here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464620/program-doesnt-wait-for-user-input-with-scanfc-yn

Comment: Not flushing `stdout` before `scanf()` might lead to things being displayed out of order, but it wouldn't cause the infinite loop here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if other characters (that aren't part of an integer) are present in the input stream before an integer can be read, `scanf()` fails and unusable data is never cleared out... which leads to an infinite loop (where `scanf()` repeatedly fails to read the same characters as an integer, over and over).

So you need to read off the invalid characters when `scanf()` fails, or as part of the format.

A simple fix would be to change your scanf from:

```
scanf("%d",&userInput);
```

to:

```
scanf("%*[^0-9]%d",&userInput);
```

to read (and discard) any characters in the input stream that aren't digits 0-9 before reading your integer... but that still doesn't check whether scanf fails for any other reason (like a closed input stream).

You could replace it with something like this:

```
int scanfRes,c;
do {
    scanfRes = scanf("%d",&userInput); /* try to read userInput */
    /* ..then discard remainder of line */
    do {
        if ((c = fgetc(stdin)) == EOF)
            return; /* ..return on error or EOF */
    } while (c != '\n');
} while (scanfRes != 1); /* ..retry until userInput is assigned */
```

..which will retry `scanf()` until the field is assigned, discarding the remainder of the line after each attempt, and exiting the function if `fgetc()` encounters an error or EOF when doing so.