# Why is this loop infinitely repeating?

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop

The purpose of this program is to count the digits in an alphanumeric input. However, I used **a loop to not execute the program unless the input is alphanumeric**.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
   int input,isanum,digitcount;
   printf("\nEnter a number: ");
   scanf("%d",&input);
   isanum=isalnum(input);

   while(isanum==0){
     printf("\nIncorrect input. Try again: ");
     scanf("%d",&input);
     isanum=isalnum(input);
   }
   digitcount=0;
   while(input!=0){
       input=input/10;
       digitcount++;
   }
   printf("\nNumber of digits = %d",digitcount);
   return 0;
}
```

The problem is with the loop. It keeps looping infinitely and **ignores the scanf statement** and I don't know why. Am I using `isalnum()` incorrectly here?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464620/program-doesnt-wait-for-user-input-with-scanfc-yn) thread.

Comment: You probably want to read characters with scanf, not integers. Otherwise, it doesn't make any sense to call isalnum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the return value of `scanf()`.

`isalnum()` takes a character, but you are passing an int.  '1' is not the same as 1 in C.

You probably should consume an entire line each time, e.g. with `fgets()`, and then check if it fits your desired input format, e.g. with `sscanf()`.

As it stands, you never consume anything, you just keep trying to read a number but there isn't one there so it fails every time.  Failing to check the return value of `scanf()` is a contributing factor to your not noticing this.

Comment: You're right. But I'm not exactly familiar with fgets() and sscanf(), could you elaborate more on how I could use them to accomplish this?

Comment: You use `fgets()` to read one entire line.  Then you pass that line to `sscanf()` or whatever other function you want, such as `strtol()` if you only want to read a single integer (it's just a simpler way than `sscanf()`).  This lets you ensure that you read a single line each time, which is probably more in line with user expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how `isalnum()` is defined: it expects a `char *`. You,  however, give it an `int *`. The data is stored completely different there.

Besides, if you are reading in an int, you know beforehand that it will be alphanumeric, right?