# why scanf("%c", &ch ) do not read the character from console while scanf(" %c", &ch ) Does

Tags: c, scanf

`scanf("%c", &ch )` do not read the character from console while `scanf("  %c", &ch )` does, the snipet from code is given under

```
printf("If the value of speed of sound is known enter Y else enter N");
scanf(" %c", &ch );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf(" %c", &ch );
```

This space before the `%c` is, probably, taking care of the buffered newline character. See [[ this ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8464649/1620779) answer.

Comment: Thanks got it. Thanks for the reference link.