# Using printf( ) in a for loop

Tags: c, printf

When attempting this (code below), the console doesn't even request an input value, then spits out a random number (likely from a number previously stored at the location).

Why does this not work and how can i fix it?

```
int main( ) {
    int arr[3];

    for(int i = sizeof(arr); i <= 0; i--) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
   }
   printf("%d", arr[2]);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(int i = sizeof(arr); i <= 0; i--)` --> `for(int i = sizeof(arr) - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826605/few-questions-about-c-syntax/7826875#7826875

Comment: `sizeof(arr)`? What do you think `sizeof(arr)` is in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that are wrong.

Assuming you want the number of elements in the array, it is done, using:

`size_t len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)`

`sizeof` gives the actual size (number of bytes allocated for arr.

1. You should start with `len - 1` and not `len`.

**NOTE**: Array indexing is **0 based** not 1 based, so the array elements are indexed from `0 to 2` But you would have tried to access arr[3], which can result in undefined behaviour.

2. You wrote `i <= 0`. So, i starts from let's say `2`, is `2 <= 0` ? NO!

Hence it will never go inside the loop. The correct condition is `i >= 0`

```
int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr);
for(int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Well, I don't know why you are taking reverse order input, but a general convention is to take input using:

```
size_t len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    // take input
}
```

EDIT:
From other comments it seems that you don't understand the `for` loop.

Have a look in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950945/6049102)

Please comment for any further clarification.

Comment: I wrote, that the questioner "intended" to have that behaviour. And even if he did that, that would be wrong.

Comment: Two nitpicks here: 1.) `sizeof` returns `size_t` not `int` 2.) The preferred pattern to calculate the size of an array by the array itself is: `char a[42]; size_t s = sizeof arr / sizeof *arr;` For completeness: `sizeof`is an *operator* and ***not*** a *function*, no need for parenthesis, it does *not* get "called".

Comment: @alk Thanks! for your input. I have updated the answer. I have a doubt though. Assume somehow `size_t len` turns out to be `0` In that case if I do `int i = len - 1;`. What will `i` contain?

Comment: For any array `T a[N];` this expression `sizeof a / sizeof *a;` will never by `<1` by definition, as the definttion `T a[0];` is *not* allowed by the C Standard. Recent versions of GCC allow it as an extension, but make it to have the size of `T`.

Comment: @alk Thanks for clarification. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
i <= 0
```

the code can never enter the loop since the initial value of i is greater than zero.

Comment: The other problem is that `sizeof` returns the size *in bytes*, so `i` will start at (probably) 12 or 24.

Comment: Isn't that the terminator of the loop though?

Comment: @HazzaOb No, the middle part of a `for` loop is like the condition of a `while` loop: As long as it is true, the loop repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Since `i--` will decrease the value of `i` , and the condition for loop is `i <=0` to start the loop the `i` must be 0 or negative.Since `arr[3]` will return 12(3 elements and each has 4 bytes(int has 4 bytes)), the value will be posivite,greater than 0 so we need to change the loop condition to check if `i` is positive

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( ) {
    int arr[3]={0};
    int i = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) -1;

    for(; i >= 0; i--) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
   }
   printf("%d", arr[2]);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arr[3]` won't return 3. `arr[3]` is not a valid element of the array (index 3 is out of bounds).

Comment: What is the "it" that's returning 0 in your question?

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` does not return 0. What are you talking about?

Comment: @melpomene I compiled again the code and returns 3 ,but few minutes ago it returned 0,strange.Anyway ,thanks a lot for contribution

Comment: No, `sizeof(arr)` will be `12` or `24` on common C implementations.

Comment: @melpomene now I have it on compiler and I use printf with %d argument and it returns 3.I know it's strange,few seconds ago it returned 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148136/discussion-between-o-rares-and-melpomene).

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that in C, other than languages like Java/Python, you must explicitly know the length of the array, `sizeof` will **NOT** give you the amount of items in the array.

```
int main() {
    int arr[3];
    int itemsInArray = 3;

    for(int i = itemsInArray-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    printf("%d", arr[2]);

   return 0;
};
```

Comment: It does give you the size of the array in bytes, though. `sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]` would work fine.

Answer (score -2):

There are a couple of issues with your code: first of all, sizeof(arr) won't return "3" as you probably thought; "arr" is a pointer to arr[0], so you are requesting the size of an int pointer.
Secondly, i <= 0 prevent the loop to even be executed.
Finally, please set array to zero while declarating, as best practice, ie:
    int arr[3] = {0};

EDIT: i wrong-spelled my thoughts: you are requesting the size of the whole memory area allocated for the array.
Comments below are corrected though.

Comment: Nah. `sizeof(anArray)` (if its known as an array like here and not decayed to a pointer), returns the size of the whole array in bytes.

Comment: Is it necessary to do the third point as all the array elements are used only as lvalue.