# Get the whole input of a string in C

Tags: c, fgets

```
#include
char option[64],line[256];

main()

{

printf(">>")
(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
            if (1 == sscanf(line, "%s", option)) {
            }
    }
print(option)
}
```

will only get the first word, for example

/>>hello world

would output

/>>hello

Comment: Print `line`, not `option`.

Comment: This is expected.  From `man scanf`:  `%s] - Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters ... The input string stops at white space`.

Comment: Look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char option[64],line[256];

    printf(">>");
    if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
        if (1 == sscanf(line, "%[^\n]%*c", option)) {//[^\n] isn't newline chars
             printf("%s\n", option);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don’t know the intention.

Answer (score 0):

In `sscanf(..., "%s" ...`

The scan terminates at whitespace, if you want to print entire line you just have to:

`printf("%s", line)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a format in `scanf` that allows you to match whitespaces. Look at @BLUEPIXY good anwser.

Alternatively, you can use `getline()`. More info [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).

Comment: I read somewhere that getline() does not limit the input buffer and is can be overflowed, not sure if my method could but I stayed away from it

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code snippet :

```
char dump, string[40];
printf("Enter the sentece with spaces:\n");
scanf ("%[^\n]", string);
scanf("%c", &dump);
printf ("You entered: %s", string);

getchar();
getchar();
```