# Objective-C : C-Style char array that won't accept spaces?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, char

Sorry to necro an old issue but (I've searched high and low for an answer to this) I noticed that the solution below does not work if the user enters spaces and multiple words.  Surely a character array can accept spaces?  If the user types a sentence, it only captures the first word:

```
char name[100]; // declaring char array
NSString *firstName; // declaring the NSString

printf("Please enter first name \n");
printf("=> ");
scanf("%s", name);

firstName = [NSString stringWithCString:name encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: The problem is not with C-style strings but with `scanf()`.

Comment: Well, actually, the problem is not with scanf, but with the failure to read the doc for scanf.

Comment: Zaph: I'm not sure I understand you. Were you talking to me?  This code is complete, aside from the #import, int main, @autoreleasepool, etc.                                                                     mouviciel: So what do you suggest?  I mean I've used scanf("%s", &name); but the & sign in there causes Xcode to complain about it having a pointer or something.

Comment: A complete example would show the inputs, outputs, and any error messages.

Comment: And, of course, before you post anything read the documentation on interfaces you're trying to use.  We're not here to read to you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of this question:

[How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

The Objective-C code is not relevant.