# How to correctly input a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, input, scanf

I am currently learning C, and so I wanted to make a program that asks the user to input a string and to output the number of characters that were entered, the code compiles fine, when I enter just 1 character it does fine, but when I enter 2 or more characters, no matter what number of character I enter, it will always say there is just one character and crashes after that. This is my code and I can't figure out what is wrong.

```
int main(void)
{
    int siz;
    char i[] = "";

    printf("Enter a string.\n");
    scanf("%s", i);

    siz = sizeof(i)/sizeof(char);

    printf("%d", siz);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I am currently learning to program, so if there is a way to do it using the same scanf() function I will appreciate that since I haven't learned how to use any other function and probably won't understand how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, FORGET that `scanf` exists. The problem you are running into, whilst caused mostly by your understandable inexperience, will continue to BITE you even when you have experience - until you stop.

Here is why:

`scanf` will read the input, and put the result in the `char` buffer you provided. However, it will **make no check** to make sure there is enough space. If it needs more space than you provided, it will overwrite other memory locations - often with disastrous consequences.

A safer method uses `fgets` - this is a function that does broadly the same thing as `scanf`, but it will only read in as many characters as you created space for (or: as you *say* you created space for).

Other observation: `sizeof` can only evaluate the size *known at compile time* : the number of bytes taken by a primitive type (int, double, etc) or size of a fixed array (like int i[100];). It cannot be used to determine the size during the program (if the "size" is a thing that changes).

Your program would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFLEN 100          // your buffer length

int main(void)    // <<< for correctness, include 'void'
{
    int siz;
    char i[BUFLEN];    // <<< now you have space for a 99 character string plus the '\0'

    printf("Enter a string.\n");
    fgets(i, BUFLEN, stdin);   // read the input, copy the first BUFLEN characters to i

    siz = sizeof(i)/sizeof(char);  // it turns out that this will give you the answer BUFLEN
                                   // probably not what you wanted. 'sizeof' gives size of array in
                                   // this case, not size of string
                                   // also not

    siz = strlen(i) - 1;           // strlen is a function that is declared in string.h
                                   // it produces the string length
                                   // subtract 1 if you don't want to count \n
    printf("The string length is %d\n", siz);  // don't just print the number, say what it is
                                               // and end with a newline: \n
    printf("hit <return> to exit program\n");    // tell user what to do next!
    getc(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps.

**update** you asked the reasonable follow-up question: "how do I know the string was too long".

See this code snippet for inspiration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 50

int main(void) {
  char a[N];
  char *b;

  printf("enter a string:\n");

  b = fgets(a, N, stdin);

  if(b == NULL) {
    printf("an error occurred reading input!\n"); // can't think how this would happen...
    return 0;
  }

  if (strlen(a) == N-1 && a[N-2] != '\n') {       // used all space, didn't get to end of line
    printf("string is too long!\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("The string is %s which is %d characters long\n", a, strlen(a)-1); // all went according to plan
  }

}
```

Remember that when you have space for N characters, the last character (at location `N-1`) must be a `'\0'` and since `fgets` includes the `'\n'` the largest string you can input is really `N-2` characters long.

Comment: You can limit the number of chars `scanf()` will read into a string by including a width for the format specifier (of one less than buffer length).. although one might as well use something else most of the time.

Comment: @Dmitri - fair point. It gets tricky to use format specifiers when the size of the buffer is variable, so I prefer the more flexible `fgets`. But is _is_ possible. Still - in my opinion `scanf` should be put into the lifeboat with three days' worth of rations and cast adrift...

Comment: Every answer certainly did give me an idea, and this one is the one I like most but, what should I do if the user inputs more characters than allowed? I mea, how can I make the program to be aware of it and to output a warning.

Comment: Happy to help. I have updated with a code snippet that shows how you can tell that the input was too large for the string buffer.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
char i[] = "";
```

is equivalent to:

```
char i[1] = {'\0'};
```

The array `i` has only one element, the program crashes because of buffer overflow.

I suggest you using `fgets()` to replace `scanf()` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LEN 1024

int main(void)
{
    char line[MAX_LEN];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
        printf("%zu\n", strlen(line) - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

The length is decremented by `1` because `fgets()` would store the new line character at the end.

Comment: Good catch that `strlen` will give string length including the `'\n'`.

Comment: @Floris Actually I didn't catch it at first :). But a simple test gives me wrong result, which reminds me forgetting something.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
char i[] = "";
```

You are essentially creating a `char array` with a size of 1 due to setting it equal to `""`;

Instead, use a buffer with a larger size:

```
char i[128]; /* You can also malloc space if you desire. */
scanf("%s", i);
```

See the link below to a similar question if you want to include spaces in your input string. There is also some good input there regarding `scanf` alternatives.

[How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Answer (score 1):

That's because `char i[] = "";` is actually an one element array.

Strings in C are stored as the text which ends with `\0` (`char` of value 0). You should use bigger buffer as others said, for example:

```
char i[100];
scanf("%s", i);
```

Then, when calculating length of this string you need to search for the `\0` char.

```
int length = 0;
while (i[length] != '\0')
{
    length++;
}
```

After running this code `length` contains length of the specified input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate space where it will put the input data. In your program, you can allocate space like:

```
char i[] = "                                     ";
```

Which will be ok. But, using `malloc` is better. Check out the man pages.

Comment: The problem with the `char i[] = " ... "`  approach is that it's not immediately obvious exactly how large the array is.  It's better to just specify the size, like `char i[257] = {0};`.  And dynamic allocation isn't *always* better...