# Simple Loops and String Length in C

Tags: c, input, while-loop, fgets

I'm pretty new to C. Writing in Visual Studio 2015, I'm trying to safely prompt a user for a string by using fgets. I want to use fgets to get the string, check if the string is too long, and reprompt the user if it is until they enter a good string. Here is my code

```
/*
* Nick Gilbert
* COS317 Lab 2 Task 2
*/
#include "stdafx.h"
int main()
{
    char str[10];
    int isValid = 0;
    while (isValid == 0) {
        printf("Please enter a password: ");
        fgets(str, 10, stdin);
        if (strlen(str) == 9 && str[8] != '\n') { //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691843/how-to-correctly-input-a-string-in-c
            printf("Error! String is too long\n\n");
            memset(&str[0], 0, sizeof(str));
        }
        else {
            printf(str);
            isValid = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Press 'Enter' to continue...");
    getchar();
}
```

However, when I run this and enter a bad string, the excess characters get fed into the next fgets automatically!

[image]

How can I fix this to do what I want it to do?

Comment: `printf(str);` --> `printf("%s\n", str);`

Comment: Best Advice - Quit Visual Studio to learn C! Start with something like CodeBlocks on Windows.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35095526/2410359) may be useful.

Comment: Checking for overly-long input is a good idea.  The problem here is that, in effect, `fgets` is already doing that for you, and what it does with the overly-long input is, it leaves it on the input stream for somebody else to read.  When you call `fgets(str, 10, stdin)` you are saying "read characters from `stdin` into `str` until you see a newline or you have read 10 characters, whichever comes first".

Comment: the reason it fails is because of your str[8] != \n. you are insisting that the 7th character is a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string read in by `fgets` doesn't end with a newline, call `fgets` in a loop until it does, then prompt the user again.

```
    if (strlen(str) > 0 && str[strlen(str)-1] != '\n') {
        printf("Error! String is too long\n\n");
        do {
            fgets(str, 10, stdin);
        } while (strlen(str) > 0 && str[strlen(str)-1] != '\n') {
    }
```

Also, never pass a variable at the first argument to `printf`, particularly if the contents of that variable comes from user entered data.  Doing so can lead to a [format string vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459630/how-can-a-format-string-vulnerability-be-exploited).

Comment: Format string vulnerabilties are actually what part 3 of this lab addresses haha

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int main()
{
    char str[10];
    int isValid = 0;
    while (isValid == 0) {
        printf("Please enter a password: ");
        fgets(str, str, stdin);
        if (strlen(str) == 9 && str[8] != '\n') { //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691843/how-to-correctly-input-a-string-in-c
            printf("Error! String is too long\n\n");
            memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
        }
        else {
            printf("%s",str);
            isValid = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Press 'Enter' to continue...");
    getchar();
}
```

In addition:

While using `memset()` you can directly use the `array_name` rather `&array_name[0]`.

Comment: Rather than `10,9,8` in `fgets(str, 10, stdin); if (strlen(str) == 9 && str[8] ...`, consider `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);  if (strlen(str) + 1 == sizeof str && str[sizeof str - 2]`.  Just like code used well  in `memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));`.