# scanf whitespace inside a function - c programming

Tags: c

From previous threads, I know that you can achieve this by using the method shown here: [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

It works in Main but when I put it inside a function, it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void dataInput();
struct record {
    char title[50];
    char author[50];
    char category[20];
    float price;
}; 

struct record info[500];

void main(){
    dataInput();
}

void dataInput(){
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x <= 10; x++ ){
        scanf("%s", &info[x].title);
        printf("%s\n", &info[x].title);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Output1]

If I use regex:

```
scanf("%50[0-9a-zA-Z ]s", &info[x].title);
```

Output:

[image: Output2]

Hmm whats wrong here

Comment: That '&' in scanf and printf arguments seems fishy.

Comment: I've remove and added them, seems to be nothing wrong. & should only be in scanf though.

Comment: It shouldn't be in either in fact. scanf takes a char* for %s.

Comment: Probably fine in this case b/c the `&` address of a `char[]` is still the beginning of the array.

Comment: @Felix true. That will be a different story with a pointer, so better get it right now though :)

Comment: try `scanf(" %49[^\n]", info[x].title);`

Comment: @Quentin Oh absolutely. Not endorsing! :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't got the most robust reference manual by hand, but from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string):

> %s : Scan a character string. The scan terminates at whitespace. A null character is stored at the end of the string, which means that the buffer supplied must be at least one character longer than the specified input length.

So `%s` does very different things in `scanf` and `printf`, and *will* in fact only read one word in `scanf`, whereas in `printf` it will yield the null terminated content pointed to.

Comment: "%s : Scan a character string", well _almost_.  In C, a string is an array of `char` up to and including the `'\0'`.  `"%s"` informs `scanf()` to 1) scan in and discard leading white-space, 2) scan in `char` until a white-space is encountered 3) unget that white-space for subsequent I/O 4) If any non--write-space was scanned append an `'\0'` to the destination.  Curiously if a rare `'\0'` is scanned, it is treated as a non-white-space character and scanning continues.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is pretty much explained here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

For the `%s` format you have this:

> Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first
>   whitespace character found. A terminating null character is
>   automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

That is why when you using a regex the problem disappears.

Comment: Yes it only works at main, but if it is inside a function, it just skipped the whole for loop. So am I stuck to have it inside main?

Comment: So if you put the whole dataInput function in the main() your code works properly?

Comment: Yes, all of the content inside the datainput function, it just works. outside, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
scanf("%[^\n]", &info[x].title);
```

Comment: **also u dont need "&" in printf**

Comment: Same thing, it just exited the for loop.

Comment: Dude the thing is, that when you use %s it accepts only upto the space, this is a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf (" %[^\n]%*c", &info[x].title);
```

Notice that **there is a SPACE before %[**, this will work correctly