# scanf() doesn't accept whitespace

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I need a scanf() call to accept whitespace (no tabs or newlines, just `' '` space glyphs).

```
char buffer[2048];
scanf(" %2048[0-9a-zA-Z ]s", buffer);
```

This format specifier I got from the answer to this question:

[how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

While it accepts the first sequence of input just fine, it terminates where the first whitespace character is, with a null character.  What's going on?  Am I perhaps using the wrong format?

I should say, I'm using scanf() here because safety isn't a concern; I'm the only person who'll ever use this particular program, and the input is rigidly formatted.

Comment: should this be something like scanf("%^[\n ]s",buffer);

Comment: need to add `&` before buffer

Comment: @SujithKarivelil - buffer is already a pointer (from the array script), so it's okay

Comment: The buffer isn't a pointer - it's an array reference, which is [not the same thing](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html). However, the array reference will [decay to a pointer](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html) when used in this manner, so it is correct to not include the `&`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `scanf("%[^\n]",buffer);`. It will accept white space.

Sample program-

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[2048];
    printf("Enter the string\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]",buffer);

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

output-

```
root@sathish1:~/My Docs/Programs# ./a.out 
Enter the string
abc def ghi ijk
abc def ghi ijk
root@sathish1:~/My Docs/Programs#
```

Answer (score 2):

Scanf isn't good for dealing with format that you're expecting to have a particular amount of whitespace. From the `scanf` man page:

> White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white space, including none, in the input.

And:

> `[`
>
> Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set of
>   accepted characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to char, and
>   there must be enough room for all the characters in the string, plus a
>   terminating NUL character.  **The usual skip of leading white space is suppressed.**

This means you can do something like

```
scanf("%[^\n]",buffer);
```

which says: "Read everything but the newline at the end of the string".

Or, if you're wanting to skip the first space, you can do:

```
scanf("%*[ ]%[^\n]",buffer);
```

This says "Read but ignore a space character, then read everything else into `buffer`".

Answer (score 1):

While you can use `scanf`, if you are reading lines of text, `getline` is preferred and provides the advantage of dynamic memory allocation (when **line = NULL**). `getline` does read/save the `newline` character, so if that isn't desired, it can be easily stripped. The following example illustrates the point:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char *line = NULL;
    ssize_t read = 0;
    size_t n = 0;

    printf ("\nEnter a line of text: ");
    read = getline (&line, &n, stdin);
    line [read - 1] = 0;  /* strip newline from string (optional) */
    read--;

    printf ("\n  read '%zd' characters: '%s'\n\n", read, line);

    return 0;

}
```

**output:**

```
./bin/getln

Enter a line of text: this is a line of text   with  white ..   ..  space.

  read '52' characters: 'this is a line of text   with  white ..   ..  space.'
```

Answer (score 0):

`fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin)` will accept or `scanf("%[\n]s",string);` will accept