# How to take the first and last name as one and print in file?

Tags: c, printf

In this code, I am facing a problem that is whenever I try to enter the `first` and `last` name, it only prints the `first` name in the file. But I want to print the `last` name also. The space between the two words should not be removed. Instead first and last should be considered as one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("new.csv", "w");
    char name[50];

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    fprintf(fp, "%s", name);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `%s`, `fscanf` read until a whitespace character appear, stopping after the first name.

If there's nothing else at the line e.g. before the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you could use `fgets` to read in the whole line. The parameters there are the file stream, a pointer to the character array and it's size:

```
char name[50];
fgets(stdin, name, sizeof(name));
```

If you still want to use scanf, you could also use `%[^\n]` instead of `%s` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25256716/13865476):

```
char name[50];
scanf("%49[^\n]", name);
```

To prevent buffer overflow, you should use `scanf` only with the buffers size minus one written directly after `%` (defining maximum field width).

If there's other data in the line after first and last name, you could read them in separately and put them together afterwards:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        char firstName[50];
        char lastName[50];
        scanf("%49s %49s", firstName, lastName);

        char name[50];
        snprintf(name, sizeof(name), "%s %s", firstName, lastName);

        printf("%s\n", name);
}
```