# How to store a bunch of strings in C?

Tags: c, string

Here in this problem , have to store n strings (with length no more of 80).

Gets function is not taking the first string (because I think the problem is new line after n). I  also tried "fgets(niza,81,stdin)" but was the same.

```
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n--)
    {
        char niza[81];
        gets(niza);
        transofrmiraj(niza,x);
        printf("%s\n",niza);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets`. It's highly deprecated & even the C standard abandoned it and advises against using it.

Comment: What to use than ?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf).

Comment: I have tried and scanf too , but scanf can't save a sentence (stops reading the string when it has a space) and in my case all the strings are sentences

Comment: Check getline function in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is probably:

```
1
String
```

When you do:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

it is only removing 1, leaving an empty newline (because you COULD have:  `1 first-string-here`).

Replacing this with:

```
scanf("%d\n",&n);
```

will cause scanf to consume that newline.

Comment: I have tried and scanf too , but scanf can't save a sentence (stops reading the string when it has a space) and in my case all the strings are sentences.

Comment: This is in regard to your first scanf, reading the number of lines.  You can use scanf for the sentences as well ( use. scanf("%[^\n]s",line. - from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256697/scanf-doesnt-accept-whitespace )

Comment: Ohh now i get it. I tried that and fgets and now its working thank you very much

Comment: @HaltState `scanf("%[^\n]",line);` -- **not `%[^\n]s`, - no `s` in there.**

Answer (score 0):

You could change:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

to:

```
scanf("%d%*c",&n);
```

So that it will read and discard the newline character after reading the integer number.

Comment: Thank you very much all of you who commented. I solve it with scanf("%d\n",&n) and fgets function.