# How to check for a blank space with scanf("%s", answer)

Tags: c, whitespace

So, I'm working on this program and I've encountered a problem with scanf. I'm scanning the input from the user in the form of a string, however if the user just presses enter, scanf doesn't pick up on it and the cursor just moves on waiting for whatever specified input I programmed it to look for. Is there anyway I can skirt around this with like a comparison to 0 or 1, or do I need to go about this in another way? Yes, this is the same program from earlier and I thought to mention this in the other post I made, but I figured this was a different problem in itself so it deserved another post separate from my other problem earlier.

```
/* 
* Scott English
* CS 1412
* tconv
* 1/28/15
*/

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *
input_from_args(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1){
        return stdin;
    }
    else {
        return fopen(argv[1], "r");
    }
}

void
rot_13(FILE *src, FILE *dest)
{
    int c,j;

    while ((c = getc(src)) != EOF)
    {
    if(c>= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    {
        if((j = c + 13) <= 'Z') 
            c = j;
        else
        {
            j = c - 13;
            c = j;
        }
    }
    else if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    {
        if((j = c + 13) <= 'z')
            c = j;
        else
        {
            j = c - 13;
            c = j;
        }
    }
    else
    c = c;

    fprintf(dest, "%c", c);
    }
}

void
convert_all_upper(FILE *src, FILE *dest)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = fgetc(src)) != EOF) 
    {
        fprintf(dest, "%c", toupper(c));
    }
}

void
convert_all_lower(FILE *src, FILE *dest)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = fgetc(src)) != EOF) 
    {
        fprintf(dest, "%c", tolower(c));
    }
}

void
print_all(FILE *src, FILE *dest)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = fgetc(src)) != EOF) 
    {
        fprintf(dest, "%c", c);
    }
}


int
main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    char answer[4];

    FILE *src = input_from_args(argc, argv);
    FILE *dest = stdout;

    printf("Please enter which conversion -r -u -l\n"); 
    scanf("%s", answer);

    if (src == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: unable to open %s\n", argv [0], argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    else if (strcmp(answer,"-r") == 0)
    { 
        rot_13(src, dest);
    }   

    else if (strcmp(answer, "-u") == 0)
    {
        convert_all_upper(src, dest);
    }           

    else if (strcmp(answer, "-l") == 0)
    {
        convert_all_lower(src, dest);
    }

    else 
    {
        printf("%s: is unsupported\n", answer);
    }   
    fclose(src);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: something like `answer[0] == '\n'` you mean?

Comment: yes, what I'm looking for is an if statement like the rest of them that takes the value of answer and compares it to a blank input. So if I run the program and hit enter, then after that point whatever I type, it will repeat back onto the screen for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Comment: yes but how would I use strcmp to compare the answer to a blank input?

Comment: ROT13: `if(c>='A' && c<='Z') c='A'+(c-'A'+13)%26; else if(c>='a' && c<='z') c='a'+(c-'a'+13)%26;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ESTRAPOLATED FROM [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)**

scanf stands for "scan formatted" and there's precious little less formatted than user-entered data. It's ideal if you have total control of the input data format but generally unsuitable for user input.

Use fgets() to get your input into a string and sscanf() to evaluate it.

A simple program to show you how to intercept the 'enter' key.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char answer[4];
    memset(answer, 0x00, sizeof(answer));

    printf("Please enter which conversion -r -u -l\n");
    fgets (answer, sizeof(answer), stdin);

    if (strlen(answer) > 0)
    {
        if (answer[0] == '\n')
        {
            printf("Empty string and enter key pressed\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Parameter %s", answer);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I keep getting an error saying there is a syntax error before else... Any idea?

Comment: Compiled with gcc 4.7.2 gives me no errors. Command **gcc test.c -Wall -o test**

Comment: No need for `-1` in `fgets (answer, sizeof(answer)-1, stdin);`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using fgets:

```
fgets(answer, sizeof answer, stdin);
```

instead of scanf, since scanf skips over whitespace including newlines, and the user won't be able to get out of the input loop.

Comment: " scanf skips over whitespace" is true for `scanf("%s", answer)` but it depends on the format - many formats specify `scanf()` to skip over whitespace, but certainly not all.

Answer (score 1):

"if the user just presses enter, scanf doesn't pick up on it" -->
`scanf("%s", answer)` is just beginning.

The `"%s"` specifies `scanf()` to scan 3 things:
1) Scan in and toss all leading white-space including `'\n'`, `' '`, `'\t'` and a few others.
2) Scan in and save an unlimited number of non-white-space `char` to `answer`.  Append a terminating `'\0'` when done.
3) Upon scanning a white-space again, put that `char` back into `stdin` for later reading.

So when a user enters <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'`, `scanf("%s", answer)` is still in step 1.

As a rule: mixing `scanf()` with `fgets()/getc()` is problematic.  Further recommend against using `scanf()` for just about all applications.  Consider:

```
// char answer[4];
// scanf("%s", answer);

char answer[4+1];
if (fgets(answer, sizeof answer, stdin) == NULL) return 1;  // stdin closed

// now remove the potential trailing '\n`.
size_t len = strlen(answer);
if (len > 0 && answer[len-1] == '\n') answer[--len] = 0;
```

Comment: ok, but I'm not wanting to remove the '\n' inputed by the user, I'm wanting to detect the '\n' so I can tell the program to do nothing and just print out what ever the user types to the screen after they type nothing and press enter.

Comment: @Senglish Then remove the last 2 code line and test for `if (answer[0] == '\n')`

Comment: @Senglish  Or leave in the 2 lines of code and test `if (answer[0] == '\0')`.  This will allow your other test like `if (strcmp(answer,"-r") == 0)`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info! I have to do my other program which is similar to this one so I will keep this in mind! Thanks a bunch!