# Spaces with scanf in a client to server message. C

Tags: c, client, server, scanf

I'm developing a client/server multithread program in C. I need to send a message from client to server with a scanf but when in the client puts a space the scanf see it as a newline. How can I read an input message with scanf including spaces? (and so the scanf don't see it as a newline?)

Thank you and I'm sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `fgets()` to get your input into a string and `sscanf()` to evaluate it. Since you just want what the user entered, you don't really need `sscanf()` in this case anyway

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)