# How to get empty input or only ENTER in C

Tags: c, string, input

Hi I'm having trouble with this simple C code since i'm very new to it.

When I try to get empty value from or get if the user only hit ENTER  without typing anything. 
Tried few variations and still not working

The piece of code is the following:

```
char user_input[17] = {'\0'};
    printf("Type something: ");
    prompt = scanf("%s", user_input);

    if (prompt <= 0) {
      printf("You didn't type anythingt!\n");
      return 1;
      }
```

Also:

```
char user_input[17] = {'\0'};
    printf("Type something: ");
    scanf("%s", user_input);

    if (user_input[0] == '\0') {
      printf("You didn't type anything!\n");
      return 1;
      }
```

There is many variations on this forum none of them worked for me...
What am I missing?

Comment: It probably contains `\n`. Use `printf` to see what is in `input_input`.

Comment: You should really read the [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Try this code: `int k; char st[20];  st[0]=0;  k=scanf("%[^\n]",st);  printf("%d %s\n",k,st);`  ... Although I think is better to use other functions! (`%[^\n]` means get all chars except `\n`)

Comment: @Sergio Formiggini  `scanf("%[^\n]",st)` will read nothing into `st` if user enters `'\n'`, leaving `st` as it was - possible uninitialized.  The `'\n'` remains in `stdin` for the next input function.

Comment: Yes, but exits! The code I"ve sent you uses st[0]=0 before to call scanf ... But there's another problem, the CR remains into the stdin ... Thus it's not a good idea to use this scanf form!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that your `scanf()` call will not return until it encounters a string that is not whitespace only. You should use `fgets()` instead, as it prevents overflow as well.

Example:

```
char s[80];
fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin);
if(s[0] == '\n') {
    puts("line is empty");
}
```

Comment: It's not true that scanf doesn't return also with only hitting enter! I tested this: `scanf("%[^\n]",str);` where `str` is (obviously) a `char *`. The result is scanf terminates also when you hit only enter! But is a better idea to use fgets!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini I meant OP's `scanf()` call, not `scanf()` in general. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can prevent the user from just pressing `[enter]` with `scanf`, but you must both:

1. check the `scanf` return, and
2. strip the newline from `stdin` on `[enter]` alone.

You must also manually prevent writing beyond the end of your string by limiting the characters `scanf` attempts to put in your array. Otherwise, `scanf` will happily try and write as many characters as are entered. (which makes **line-oriented** input like `fgets` or `getline` preferable)

However, if you take that all into consideration, you can do what it looks like you are attempting with `scanf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXS 17

void fflush_stdin();

int main () {

    char user_input [MAXS] = {0};   /* always initialize your variables */

    while (printf ("\n Type something (16 char or less): ") && 
            scanf ("%16[^\n]%*c", user_input) < 1) 
    {
        printf (" pressing [enter] doesn't count...\n");
        fflush_stdin();
    }
    printf ("\n   You entered: '%s'\n\n", user_input);

    return 0;
}

/* simple function to strip '\n` from stdin */
void fflush_stdin()
{ int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); }
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanfbasic1

 Type something (16 char or less):
 pressing [enter] doesn't count...

 Type something (16 char or less):
 pressing [enter] doesn't count...

 Type something (16 char or less): 12345678901234567890

   You entered: '1234567890123456'
```

---

### getline Solution

As mentioned above, **line-oriented** input is the preferred manner for reading strings. Two of the primary tools available are `fgets` and `getline`. Both have strengths/weaknesses. Two of the primary strengths of `getline` is that it **(1)** will allocate the line buffer for you, and **(2)** it returns the actual number of characters read into the buffer.

A weakness of `getline` is it will read all characters it is given up to the point of memory exhaustion. So if you are limiting your input to `17` (16 chars + null-terminator), it is up to you to enforce the limit. A weakness of `fgets` is that you have no way of knowing how many characters were actually read. All you know is `fgets` read somewhere between `1` and `max length` generally prompting the need to call `strlen` (or iterate over the string until the null-terminator is found.)

Both `fgets` and `getline` will include the trailing `'\n'` in the buffer (as it exists in the file, or as produced when you press `[enter]` when reading from `stdin`). It is never a good idea to leave stray newlines hanging off the ends of your strings, so it is generally a good idea to strip the newline after it is read.

**note:** `getline` will allocate memory for the buffer if the buffer is initially set to `NULL` ..**and**.. `getline` will reallocate the buffer it is given if it is insufficient to hold the input. (the current size of the allocation is maintained in `'n'`). Since `getline` allocates/reallocates for you, you are responsible for freeing the memory when it is no longer in use.

Taking all that into consideration, the following is an equivalent `getline` implementation that prevents the user from leaving an empty string by simply pressing `[enter]` at the prompt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXS 17

int main (void) {

    char *ln = NULL;    /* getline requires block allocated by malloc       */
    size_t n = 0;       /* initial size of buffer, if ln NULL, n ignored    */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;   /* getline return - number of chars actually read   */

    while (printf ("\n Type something (16 char or less): ") &&
            ((nchr = getline (&ln, &n, stdin)) <= 1)) { 
        printf (" pressing [enter] doesn't count...\n");
    }

    while (nchr > 0 && (ln[nchr-1] == '\n' || ln[nchr-1] == '\r'))
        ln[--nchr] = 0;     /* strip newline or carriage rtn    */

    if (nchr > MAXS - 1)    /* to enforce limit, check length   */
        ln[MAXS - 1] = 0;   /* if exceeds limit, null-terminate */

    printf ("\n   You entered: '%s'\n\n", ln);

    if (ln) free (ln);      /* free memory allocated by getline */

    return 0;
}
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getlinebasic_noenter

 Type something (16 char or less):
 pressing [enter] doesn't count...

 Type something (16 char or less): 12345678901234567890

   You entered: '1234567890123456'
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why everyone is giving complex solutions.

You can just use the 'system' function and give it "pause" which will check for any key press and then exit the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Whatever code here...

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

This is a  simple solution which works for windows.

Comment: Key thing being `Windows` here ;) If that's the only target platform, yes, it's fine. But it doesn't have to be the case.