# Need help about function scanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

I'm reading book "C Programming A Modern Approach" and I see a question:
Show how can be distinguished: `"%f"` vs `"%f "`(after %f have a space) in function `scanf()`.

Can you help me understanding how does `"%f "` work.

Comment: There is some useful scanf related information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf

Comment: You can see more detail about `scanf()` function in [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/). Read description of `format`, answer of your question is explained so clearly.

Answer (score 3):

`"%f"` instructs `scanf()` to

1. Scan from `stdin` and discard white-space until no more input or a non-white-space encountered.  Put that `char` back into `stdin`.
2. Scan `char` that represents a `float`.  Continue until no more input or a non-`float` `char` encountered.  Put that `char` back into `stdin`.

`"%f "` instructs `scanf()` to the steps 1 and 2 above and then

3. Scan from `stdin` and discard white-space until no more input or a non-white-space encountered.  Put that `char` back into `stdin`.  (just like step 1)

---

Note:  All `scanf()` format specifiers except `"%c"`, `"%n"`, `"%[]"` perform step 1 before scanning further.

Answer (score 0):

The second one required a space followed by a float you entered. If you have multiple float to take from user then you can write something like -

```
scanf("%f %f", &f1, &f2);
```

Comment: @Nguyen. I believe the only 'spaces' that scanf ignores are: tab, space bar & newline ('enter' key) present in the input stream. When the 'space' is in between format specifiers e.g. scanf("%f  %f", ...), it is ignored. But in your second example, there is no other format specifier after the space i.e. ("%f  ") ... so it probably expects more data in the stream. Then, after you enter 'something', it attempts to store it in a variable, but since there is only 1 variable 'x' e.g. scanf("%f  ", &x), it ignores the 'something' you entered ... and returns.

Comment: @Nguyễn Văn-Dũng, why are using slang here. You may down vote if you think some post (answer/question) is incorrect of of low quality. Please don't use slang.

Comment: @iammowgli In the default `"C"` locale, white-spaces are space `' '`, form feed `'\f'`, new-line `'\n'`, carriage return `'\r'`, horizontal tab `'\t'`, and vertical tab `'\v'`.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the white-space after `%f`, that is

```
scanf("%f ");
```

the `scanf()` will skip the line-feed character.

Comment: Note: It will skip a following line-feed character as well an any number of following white-space.