# Splitting a user-entered String into separate tokens by white space in C

Tags: c, string, split, token, tokenize

I am trying to print a user entered string word by word, or tokenize. I have:

```
char input [1000]; 

char* token;
scanf("%s", input);

token = strtok (input," ,.");

while (token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n",token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ,.");
}
```

When I enter something into the console, say "test test one two three.", only the first word is printed out.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: I am just starting out in C. Quite the transition from Java. Because of this, I don't have any familiarity with debugging practices for C code yet.

Comment: Heres a tip, try using `printf` to print out the string `input` ....

Comment: Wow, thanks. I see that it is not storing correctly. Only the first word is being stored into input. I don't know why though. Is it because I need to be scanning in an array of char arrays rather than a single char array?

Comment: You probably want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf) then.

Comment: Scanf() is not terribly useful try just getting the entire user input as everything up to and including a newline with fgets() or getline().

Comment: man scanf, especialy '%s' format specifier....

Comment: Note that `%s` means 'stop at the first blank.  So, the problem is not the `strtok()` loop; it is the data that is passed to it. Use standard C [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html)
or perhaps POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read a whole line, and then watch the parsing work. NB: A very simple debugging technique is to print the value that was just read, so that you know what the computer got. That would have told you what the trouble is, or at least completely changed the question asked.

Comment: Note that for many purposes, it is a lot easier to control `fgets()` and use `sscanf()` on the input line than to use `scanf()` directly.  Except when I'm answering questions on SO that use `scanf()`, I don't use it — and the answers quite often end up using `fgets()` and `sscanf()` instead.

Comment: I see now. Got it working, thanks everybody.I understand now that fgets() is much more suitable for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only scanning in the first word with `scanf`. `scanf`expects a formatted string input, ie in your case:

```
scanf("%s %s %s %s", string1, string2 ...
```

This isnt useful to you. You should look into using [`fgets`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm).

**Please be aware that `gets` has no way of limiting input size.** It can be very dangerous for your memory if not used only by you. Use `fgets`.

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/9TIbwQ)

Comment: Wrong. [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) is OK, but you should _**never**_ use [`gets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gets.html). The `gets()` function is inherently, unfixably buggy, because it will read an unlimited amount of data as long as it's all one "line". There's no way to limit the input to the size of the input buffer.

Comment: @Thisisn'tmyrealname You are right, i have added a note. `gets` is fine for experimentation or for use in very constrained examples, but i agree in using `fgets` over `gets` and `scanf`. I have also fixed the example.

Comment: i prefer `fgetc` to manage the buffer myself, when reading from `stdin`

Comment: @self what do you do differently to `fgets` which looks for `\n` or `EOF`?

Comment: latest program, checked for `\n` then closed the buffer, ('\0'), also checked `i` to make sure it wouldn't over-run the `sizeof(buffer) - 1`, if `i` was equal, stop, and append `\0' `at i++`

Comment: @self I am pretty sure that `fgets` does exactly those things. Except for checking `\0` terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with `strtok`. While you can use `scanf`, there is the significant limitation that you must *hardcode* the maximum number of strings you plan to convert. In the event you use something like:

```
scanf("%s %s %s %s", string1, string2 ...
```

Your conversion to tokens will fail for:

```
one two three four five
```

So, unless you are guaranteed a set number of strings before you write your code, `scanf` will not work. Instead, as with your initial attempt, your choice of `strtok` will provide the flexibility to handle an unlimited number of words.

Your only problem reading input initially was the choice of the `scanf` file specifier of `"%s"` where conversion stops when the first *whitespace* is encountered. If you simply changed your conversion specifier to `"%[^\n]"` your would have been able to read all words in the string up to the `'\n'` character. However, a better alternative to `scanf` is probably `fgets` in this situation. A quick example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 256

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC] = {0};
    char *p = buf;

    printf ("\n enter words: ");
    fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin);

    printf ("\n tokens:\n\n");
    for (p = strtok (buf, " "); p; p = strtok (NULL, " \n"))
        printf ("   %s\n", p);

    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtok_fgets

 enter words: a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

 tokens:

   a
   quick
   brown
   fox
   jumps
   over
   the
   lazy
   dog.
```

If you would like to use `scanf`, then you could replace `fgets` above with `scanf ("%255[^\n]", buf);` and accomplish the same thing.