# Trying to take someone's full name and return their initials in C

Tags: c

I am new to C and I am trying to write a program that takes an entered name, like john smith, and returns the uppercase initials, JS. I've tried using a for loop and a while loop, but my code does not seem to increment, whenever I run it all it returns is the first initial. I've searched the web for this problem, but none of the solutions worked for me. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  // initialize variables
  char name[61];
  int i = 0;

  // ask for user input
  printf("Please enter your name: ");
  scanf("%s", name);

  // print first initial
  printf("%c", toupper(name[0]));

  // print the next ones
  while (name[i] != '\0') {
    if (name[i] == ' ') {
      i++;
      printf("%c", toupper(name[i+1]));
    }
    i++; // does not increment
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf

Comment: Don't forget to replace `i++;` in the `if` with  `if(isalpha(name[i+1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` reads the input until a space is encountered. So writing the full name will have a space in between the first and the last name. That would stop `scanf()` and it would read only the first name.

To read both input with space, better use `fgets()`. `fgets()` reads the string until a newline `\n` is encountered.

```
fgets(name, 61, stdin);
```

Comment: @jedimaster7, you're welcome. And do gift me a light saber if possible.. ;)

Comment: @jedimaster7, BTW, you don't know the power of the dark side. ;)

Comment: I would gift you one if I knew you wouldn't use it for the dark side... ;)

Comment: @jedimaster7, You know I would ultimately turn good, lemme have a little fun with the dark side.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%s", name)` only reads the first name. You need something like `scanf("%s %s", first_name, last_name)`

Comment: thanks :), I didn't know that scanf() stops after the first word

Comment: @jedimaster7 `%s` in `scanf` scans until a whitespace character.