# How do i prinf Struct array?

Tags: c

I am trying to printf the values in the structs from 2 arrays but the output gets very wierd and I dont know why.

this is whats get outputed:
c123
6545645
bvabc123
vabc123
abc132

this should be outpued:
Johan
47
Car
Volvo
abc123

**whats wrong?**

```
struct person{
    char name;
    int age;
};
typedef struct person p;

struct vehicle{
    char type;
    char brand;
    char regn;
    char owner;
};
typedef struct vehicle v;

int main(){
    p owner[1];
    v Vehicle[1];

    for(int i=0; i<1;i++){
        printf("Name\n");
        scanf("%s",&owner[i].name);
        printf("Age\n");
        scanf("%d",&owner[i].age);
        printf("Type\n");
        scanf("%s",&Vehicle[i].type);
        printf("Brand\n");
        scanf("%s",&Vehicle[i].brand);
        printf("regn\n");
        scanf("%s",&Vehicle[i].regn);


    }

    for(int j=0; j<1; j++){
        printf("%s\n", &owner[j].name);
        printf("%d\n", &owner[j].age);
        printf("%s\n", &Vehicle[j].type);
        printf("%s\n", &Vehicle[j].brand);
        printf("%s\n", &Vehicle[j].regn);
    }

}
```

Comment: `man 3 printf`, and `%d` takes an int, not a memory address ( pointer )

Comment: i know but its very wierd becasue if i dont use & the program stops runnin when i start it. Sorry im very new to coding. @self

Comment: Hint: `char` does not mean what you think it does.

Comment: A `char` is one character, not a string

Comment: Hm I see. Is the solution to make an array to every char?

Comment: That is a possible soultion

Comment: Okay thank u every1. What about the int? I think the scanf shoulb be without & becase it already have an adress or im I wrong? without & it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `char` is supposed to be a single character such as `'a'`, `'B'`, `'1'`, ect. and so what you need is an array of them. Below I arbitrarily chose 32 as the lengths of the arrays

Note that I removed `&` from several places in your code because it is now using arrays rather than single characters:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct person {
    char name[32];
    int age;
};
typedef struct person p;

struct vehicle {
    char type[32];
    char brand[32];
    char regn[32];
    char owner[32];
};
typedef struct vehicle v;

int main(){
    p owner[1];
    v Vehicle[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        printf("Name\n");
        scanf("%s", owner[i].name);
        printf("Age\n");
        scanf("%d", &owner[i].age);
        printf("Type\n");
        scanf("%s", Vehicle[i].type);
        printf("Brand\n");
        scanf("%s", Vehicle[i].brand);
        printf("regn\n");
        scanf("%s", Vehicle[i].regn);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
        printf("%s\n", owner[j].name);
        printf("%d\n", owner[j].age);
        printf("%s\n", Vehicle[j].type);
        printf("%s\n", Vehicle[j].brand);
        printf("%s\n", Vehicle[j].regn);
    }
}
```

Also note that this code will cause undefined behavior if the user inputs a string that overflows the storage space of 32 because it does not check for that. Additionally if the user inputs white space for any of the `scanf` that will cause problems. There is a solution to this if that is important to you here: [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Answer (score 1):

A `char` in C literally means a single character. A `char` is just simply a signed 8 bit integer. So when you write `char` in code, you're telling C that you're storing a single 8 bit integer - nothing more than that. A string, on the other hand, consists of many characters, where each character is an 8 bit integer (ie. a `char`). In C, strings are stored as consecutive 8 bit integers in memory (an array), where the array's length is one more than the length of the string, and this extra element at the end of the array is a null terminator (a single byte which is just a 0). Since strings can be of any length, we need to know how long they are (ie. where the array in memory ends). C does this by having this null terminator at the end of the string.

In your code, when you write `char` in a struct definition, you are telling C to only store a single character. What you want is a `char *` (pointer to a `char`), which points to an array of `char`s, where the last element is a null terminator. C inserts this terminator for you if you use double quotes when assigning the string.

What you want is something like this:

```
typedef struct person {
  char *name;
  // ...
} p;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  p person;
  person.name = "The name";
  printf("%s\n", person.name); // Prints `The name`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First,for name,type,brand and regn variables,they are strings,so you should use char array to define them.

Second,you shouldn't use & in scanf function,when the variable is array;
Last,you shouldn't use & in printf function.

last,you shouldn't use & in printf function.

```
scanf("%s",owner[i].name);
printf("%s\n",owner[j].name);
```