# How to properly scan in input into a struct in C and display it back out?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

So i have a struct named person with all their information and i want the user to be able to input them and then display it all back to the user. Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person{
    char name[30];
    char address[30];
    int phoneNumber[30];
    char creditRating[30];
};

int main(){
    struct person p;
    printf("What is the person's name?\n");
    scanf(" %s", p.name);
    printf("What is the person's address?\n");
    scanf(" %s", p.address);
    printf("What is the person's phone number?\n");
    scanf("%d", &p.phoneNumber);
    printf("What is the person's credit rating?\n");
    scanf(" %s", p.creditRating);

    printf("The person's name is %s\n", p.name);
    printf("The person's address is %s\n", p.address);
    printf("The person's phone number is %d\n", p.phoneNumber);
    printf("The person's credit rating is %s\n", p.creditRating);
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is that it won't properly take in an address that has spaces and numbers. Also, when i input a phone number, it doesn't properly display. All the numbers are random. How do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf

Comment: `int phoneNumber[30];` is incorrect. Subject does not have 30 phone numbers. And `scanf` with a string type stops at the first whitespace. I suggest having a good read about format specifiers. Ir's quite complicated.

Comment: I would use `unsigned long long phoneNumber;`, and print it using `%llu`. Weather is right, you don't need an array.

Comment: "when i input a phone number, it doesn't properly display" -->  Rather than  weakly _describe_ the output, post the input, the true output and the expected output.  Much more useful.

Comment: Since phone numbers can 1) begin with 0, 2) contain "#*" and 3) sometimes "-" is useful, suggest simply reading the phone number like any other text.  Also, robust code avoids `scanf()`.  Better to use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 4):

One's phone number usually have 11 digits or so, and it's not guaranteed that an `int` or `unsigned long long` is large enough to hold it. So I think your `struct person` should be defined as

```
struct person {
    char name[30];
    char address[30];
    char phoneNumber[20];
    char creditRating[10];
};
```

And `scanf("%s", str)` stops when a whitespace is encountered, can this can be a bug, because people usually have one or more spaces in their names. To input a string containing `' '` , use `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)`.

Also, `scanf()` is buffer-overflow vulnerable, so your program may crash if user input is too long to be hold in the designated array. `fgets()` gives you buffer overflow protection. Don't forget to remove the tailing `'\n'` by `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';` if you're using `fgets()`.

---

Here is a demo code:

```
printf("What is the person's name?\n");
fgets(p.name, sizeof p.name, stdin);
p.name[strcspn(p.name, "\n")] = '\0';

printf("The person's name is %s\n", p.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing a helper function allows code to nicely encapsulate user I/O and handle a number of issues.

Recommend use a string for the phone number too.  So instead of an array of `int`, use `char phoneNumber[30]`.  The code can post-process things like `-` and deal with leading zeros, etc.

```
// Candidate improvements: cope with long lines, 
// remove need for user buffer to temporarily store the \n
int GetString(char *dest, size_t size, const char *prompt) {
  fputs(prompt, stdout);
  fflush(stdout);
  if (fgets(dest, size, stdin) == NULL) {
    dest[0] = '\0';
    return EOF;
  }
  dest[strcspn(dest, "\n")] = '\0';
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  struct person p;
  GetString(p.name,        sizeof p.name,        "What is the person's name?\n");
  GetString(p.address,     sizeof p.address,     "What is the address?\n");
  GetString(p.phoneNumber, sizeof p.phoneNumber, "What is the person's phone number?\n");
  GetString(p.creditRating,sizeof p.creditRating,"What is the person's credit rating?\n");

  printf("The person's name is %s\n", p.name);
  printf("The person's address is %s\n", p.address);
  printf("The person's phone number is %s\n", p.phoneNumber);
  printf("The person's credit rating is %s\n", p.creditRating);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really have to forget scanf... +1 for the helper function, BTW.

Comment: @Bob__  I've been there.  I was ready to up-vote you given the comment about `fgets()`, but the `scanf()` implementation has its holes with evil user input.  About all production code I use now involves some wrapper to cope with the various weaknesses of C I/O functions.