# C pointer arithmetic array remove chars

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pointers, char

I am writing a program that takes a user's comment. Specifically one that has input outside of `/*` and `*/` and also inside. I have written my loop to find the char `"/"` in my array and I am unsure how to remove it and everything in between it until it appears again. For example if my input was `"comment /* this is my comment */"` I need to remove the `/*` `*/` and contents between. So my output would just be `"comment"`. If there is no `"/* and */"` it doesn't remove anything. I know I need a loop but how would I write a loop that removes chars in the array until the next `"/"` appears and removes it as well? 
My code is as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void remove_comment(char *s1, char *s2){

  for(; *s1 != '\0'; s1++){  //loops through array until null value
    if(*s1 == '/'){  //if array has '/' stored
                     //clear array elements till next '/' and removes it as well
  }
    else{
    return; //do nothing to array
  }
  strcpy(s2,s1); //copies new modified string to s2 for later use
}

int main(){

  char s1[101]; //declares arrays up to 100 in length with room for null character
  char s2[101];

  printf("Enter a comment: "); //enter a comment
  fgets(s1, 100, stdin);  // saves comment to array

  remove_comment(s1,s2);  //calls function

  printf("%s", s2); //prints my modified array 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You just need to find the start and end positions of the comment, then substring and concatenate using those positions

Comment: It could be a detail, but reading your input with scanf() will ignore everything that follows the first whitespace (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Comment: @Christophe Thank you, since time of posting I have changed to `fgets()`

Comment: `return` returns from the function, it doesn't "do nothing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to build on a loop exploring the chars of the string.  I propose you therefore the following solution:

```
void remove_comment(char *s1, char *s2) 
{
    for(int in_comment=0; *s1 ; s1++){  //loops through array until null value
      if(!in_comment && *s1 == '/' && s1[1]=='*') {  //if array has '/' follewed by '*' stored
          in_comment=1;    // we enter a comment area
          s1++; 
      }
      else if (in_comment) {     // if we are in a comment area
          if (*s1=='*' && s1[1]=='/') {    // we only look for end of comment
              in_comment = 0; 
              s1++;
          }
      }
      else *s2++=*s1;       // if we're not in comment, in all other cases we just copy current char
    }
    *s2='\0'; // don't forget to end the string. 
}
```

It uses a `in_comment` variable to tell if we are currently exploring chars in the comment (and looking for an end of comment) or not (and looking eventually for a start of comment).

It uses `*s1` and `s1[1]` to access the current and the next char.

It leaves the original string unchanged.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/L07oF5)

Comment: I was trying to get away from using array[] in my function and using pointers rather. I should have explained that. I do realize that it isn't how comments work in C but rather it is just an input string from the user.

Comment: I see a problem when the `"/*"` appears, but no `"*/"`

Comment: @chux the `/*/` will be interpreted as a start of comment and the rest of the string is ignored if there's no end of comment.  `/**/` is safely ignored.  You can test all this in the online demo, chainging the input string

Comment: OP has "If there is no "/* and */" it doesn't remove anything."

Comment: I like this answers ability to remove 2+ comments like `"abc /* def */ abc /* def */ abc"` .

Comment: @chux If there's "no `/*` and no `*/`" this code removes noting as expected.   If OP meant "if there is an `/*`  but no `*/` it removes nothing", then indeed this code should indeed be adapted (i.e. keep a copy of start pointer when entering a comment, and use a `strcpy()` from this start pointer in case end of string is reached and still in comment)

Comment: @Chux by the way, it would be easy to add an `in_quote` state  if there would be a need to ignore `/*` when it appears between quote or double quote.

Comment: True the unmatched `"/*"` requirement is open to interpretation.  +1 for your nice state-machine.  BTW: I see 5+ C states: in_code, in_slash_comment, in slash_slash_comment, in_quote, in_double_quote, maybe in_pre-process (ignoring tri-graphs), maybe in_escape_seq

Answer (score 1):

> I know I need a loop

Could use a loop, or use standard library functions.  Consider `char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);` as a candidate part of a solution.

> The `strstr` function locates the first occurrence in the string pointed to by `s1` of the sequence of characters (excluding the terminating null character) in the string pointed to
>   by `s2`.
>
> The `strstr` function returns a pointer to the located string, or a null pointer if the string is not found.

Some untested code to give you an idea.

```
void remove_comment(const char *src, char *dest){
  char *start = strstr(str, "/*");        // Look for beginning
  if (start) {                            // Find the beginning?
    char *end = strstr(start + 2, "*/");  // Now search 2 past
    if (end) {                            // Find the end?
      memcpy(dest, src, start - src);
      strcpy(&dest[start - src], end+2);
      return;
    }
  }
  strcpy(dest, src);
}
```

---

If you want to avoid library funcitons, I'll pass along a hint

```
// if(*s1 == '/'){ 
if(s1[0] == '/' && s1[1] == '*') {
```

---

Of course this is insufficient for finding `/*  */` comments in C code like:

```
puts("/* this is not a C comment, but a string literal */");
int a = '/*', b = '*/'; 
// start of comment /* xyz */
```

Comment: Nice use of `strstr()` ;-)