# sscanf not working space from stdin

Tags: c, string, space, scanf

I have some issue with sscanf function in C.

**My program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char str[50];
    int y=0, x=0;

    printf("Insert string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    sscanf(str, "%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("x:%d  y:%d\n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
10 20
```

**Output**

```
x:10  y:0
```

I also tried

```
sscanf(str, "%d%d", &x, &y);
```

and

```
sscanf(str, "%d%*[ \n\t]%d", &x, &y);
```

but the output is the same.

The strange thing is that when I try

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char str[] = "10 20";
    int y=0, x=0;

    sscanf(str, "%d %d", &x, &y);
    printf("x:%d  y:%d\n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

my output is `x:10  y:20`

Comment: if you output your `str` after the `scanf("%s", str);`, you'll find the poblem.

Comment: `%s` stops reading input at the first whitespace character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not because `sscanf` fault, it's that `scanf` ignore whitespace.

As pointed out many times ([How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)), you should use `fgets` instead to get string input.

So replacing `scanf("%s", str);` with the line below would work:

```
fgets( str, 50, stdin );
```