# Different behaviour of scanf

Tags: c, input, scanf

Is there some difference between

```
scanf("%s", c);
```

and

```
scanf(" %s", c);
```

Like can it affect my program in any way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chk this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf

Comment: That's an entirely different question

Comment: No, there is no difference.

Comment: It will do the same operation.

Comment: You may have to read between the lines. Leaving a `space` before the *format specifier* causes `scanf` to skip leading *whitespace* before making the conversion. So depending on your input, yes, it can effect your program. See `man scanf` following *"A directive is one of the following:"*

Comment: A buffer overrun occurs if `char` is a char type.

Comment: Please read my question carefully I haven't asked how to scan a string with a space in it.

Comment: Please read the comments carefully, we're not telling you how to read a string with a space in it (although that is what the *answer* is telling you)

Comment: @Sanjay-sopho You can use `scanf("%s", c)` instead `scanf("%s", &c)` since array name is a constant pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `scanf` `%s` conversion specifier skips leading whitespace characters and parses a word up to and not including subsequent whitespace.

Adding a space in front of the `%s` has no effect, it is fully redundant.

The same holds for `%d` and `%f` but not `%c` or `%[`.

Note also that the `%s` and `%[` specifiers are risky since you do not provide `scanf` any limit for the number of characters to store into the destination. This might be OK for `sscanf()` as the conversion is implicitly limited by contents of the source string, but must be avoided for `scanf` and `fscanf`.

You can provide a numeric argument between the `%` and the `s` for the maximum number of chars to store before the null terminator:

```
    char buffer[100];
    if (scanf("%99s", buffer) == 1) {
        /* a word was parsed correctly into buffer */
    }
```