# reading a line(with spaces) into a string assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, stdin, fgets

```
  ; push stdin here
    push MAX_N             ; maximum number of characters to be read 
    push offset string     ;pointer to an array of chars
    call fgets
    add esp,12
```

I tried to read into "string" variable a line(with spaces too). I can't do that with scanf so i chose instead to use fgets

But, how can i push standard input there ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf  seems like gets has the same problem like scanf

Comment: Did you try the obvious `extern stdin` / `push [stdin]`?  It should be a global variable with static storage that holds a `FILE*` value.  And yes, `push r/m32` can push a memory operand directly.  Any time you get stuck in asm, look at compiler output for a function that does what you want.

Comment: @PeterCordes That doesn't work everywhere. For example, on FreeBSD the symbol is called `__stdinp`.