# How can I enter space bar as input using scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm writing an fuction and I got a problem, the scanf function cant read spacebar " ", how can I solve it?

```
void add()
{
char choose2;   

FILE *fp;
struct booking book;    
system("cls");          
fp=fopen("hotelbooking.txt","a");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {   
        printf("There are no data file!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Add New Hotel Booking Record(s)\n");

        printf("  Name of Traveller: \n");  
        scanf("%s",book.travellername);
        fprintf(fp,"\n%s",book.travellername);

        printf("  Destination: ");  
        scanf("%s",book.destination);
        fprintf(fp,"\n%s",book.destination);                            
        fclose(fp);     
    }               
}
```

In the tervellername part, If I want to enter e.g. "Jason George", How can I scan the space bar between the name?

I'm using the structure below:

```
    struct booking
    {
    char travellername[20];
    char destination[20];
    }book;
```

Comment: You want only a newline (Return or Enter) to terminate the input?

Comment: I have tried gets() but it wont let me enter anythings, it just skip the line

Comment: @StoryTeller I want something similar to scanf but i can enter wors with space e.g. "The Pen"

Comment: Then the duplicate question has all the approaches that can be suggested

Comment: @KinHangLee  Welcome to Stack Overflow! [DO NOT use `gets()`, it is dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2173917). use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf()` with `%s` format specifier stops scanning as soon as it hits a whitespace. You cannot scan `space` using it.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2,

> `s` Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters.

For a better and robust alternative, you can use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to scan an entire line, terminated by a `newline`. Remember, in this case, `fgets()` scans and stores the terminating newline also in the supplied buffer, so you need to manually get rid of it, if that matters.

Comment: Detail: "scanf() with %s format specifier stops scanning as soon as it hits a whitespace"  --> With `"%s"` leading spaces do not stop scanning, they are consumed and not saved.  It is spaces after non-white-space that stops scanning with `"%s"`.  This is not directly observed with  OP's example which has a middle space.  Good suggestion about `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

```
scanf("%[^\n]", book.travellername);
```

Input string will read space separated words and terminate upon encountering a newline character (i.e. `\n`). Also be Careful that this does not get buffer overflows. so define size of `book.travellername` accordingly.

**update:** I have updated the format specifier.

Comment: The `s` isn't part of the format specifier.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't understand. this used to work for space separated input.

Comment: Look at the specification for scanf. There's `%s` and `%[]`. I also must mention that I didn't downvote, just wanted to point out what I thought was a typo.