# Using scanf to store string in a structure

Tags: c, arrays, function, structure, scanf

I've written a function that stores information on books to a struct Book and everything is working fine except for when the book title has any white spaces. So something like `Dracula` will be stored and displayed just fine, but something like `Lord of the Rings` will just skip scanning for the rest of the book's information and proceed to close the program. Is there any way to use scanf to register the string with the white spaces? Here's my code:

```
void addBook(struct Book book[], int *size)
{
        if(*size== MAX_BOOKS) {
                printf("the inventory is full.\n");
        }

        else {
                printf("ISBN\n");
                scanf("%d", &book[*size]._isbn);
                printf("Title\n");
                scanf("%s", book[*size]._title);
                printf("Price\n");
                scanf("%f", &book[*size]._price);
                printf("Year\n");
                scanf("%d", &book[*size]._year);
                printf("Qty\n");
                scanf("%d", &book[*size]._qty);
                printf("Book successfully added to inventory\n");

                (*size)++;
                }

}
```

I can update with the full code if necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you allow spaces to be entered using scanf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247989/how-do-you-allow-spaces-to-be-entered-using-scanf)

Comment: you can use `fgets()` or `getline()` or `scanf("%[^\n]s",name);`

Comment: I've tried `scanf("%[^\n]s", book[*size]._title);` and it skips the input altogether.

Comment: Try this:
`printf("Title\n");
                getchar();
                gets(&book[*size]._title);
`

Comment: So the scanf reads every character so long as the user does not proceed to newline with enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem. That's because %s stops at the first space. Use %[^\n] so it reads until he find the enter.